# How do I update devDependencies in NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

`npm update` seems to just update the packages in `dependencies`, but what about `devDependencies`.

Right now you can install `devDependencies` by running `npm install .`, but this doesn't work for `npm update .`

Any ideas?

Comment: I just ran into the same thing. I'm surprised at this asymmetry between `npm install` and `npm update`. I worked around it by deleting my `node_modules` directory and then running `npm install` again, but it sure seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: I opened a [bug report](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2369) for this behavior. We'll see what happens.

Comment: This may be because the NPM devs thought that people would use `npm link` for doing dev environments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-to-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version)

Answer (score 186, accepted):

To update package.json in addition to the local modules, run

```
npm update --save-dev
```

Alternatively, the same command to save time

```
npm update -D
```

You can view the full detail of update, or any command for that matter through

```
npm help <cmd>
```

Comment: `npm update -D` did not work for me, it didn't update anything.

Comment: Why is this marked as the correct answer when the question is not how to save updates to `package.json` but rather how to make `npm update` to update devDependencies?

Comment: @onalbi: it does not. Here's the [thread tracking the issue](https://npm.community/t/npm-update-doesnt-save-package-json/872/6?u=dandv).

Comment: `npm update --save-dev` works just fine for me. Using node `v12.11.0` and npm `v6.11.3`

Comment: Nothing from the stated is working! (Downvoting).

Answer (score 67):

Install npm-check-updates (https://www.npmjs.org/package/npm-check-updates), then jump into your project folder and run:

```
npm-check-updates
```

And to update and save changes to your package.json file:

```
npm-check-updates -u
```

Comment: `ncu` would be better than `npm-check-updates` to save typing.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa there's a `-d` option for devDependencies only

Comment: ncu --dep dev -u;               
npm install

Comment: This may update vue dependencies to a higher version than the latest version that vue-cli supports.

Answer (score 20):

These steps worked for me :

1. `npm install -g npm-check-updates`
2. `ncu -u`
3. `npm update`
4. `npm install`

Comment: Why we have to use third party thing for this kind of work? So weird. I could not make npm update change package.json

Comment: 3. is probably not needed, you can skip it.

Comment: step 4. is obviated by step 3.  The response from @Daniel Danielecki  does a better job of explaining what each of these steps actually does. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68375286/413538

Comment: This updates to the very latest version, ignoring all semantic rules like ^. ~. Is there any options to update following semantic rules?

Answer (score 13):

1. `npm outdated` - for an overview what's outdated
2. `npm install -g npm-check-updates` - as pointed correctly by Michael
3. `ncu -u` - it'll **automatically** update all dependencies (also `dependencies`, i.e., it's of course different than `devDependencies`) versions in `package.json`, without reinstalling it yet. It'll just change the "numbers" in `package.json`
4. `npm update` - actual dependencies installation
5. (Optional, depending by scenario) you **might** need to use the flag `--force`, or (new in NPM v7) `--legacy-peer-deps` to complete the process. You can read about difference between those 2 on [What does npm install --legacy-peer-deps do exactly? When is it recommended / What's a potential use case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh)
6. (Optional) you can validate it using `ncu -u` and for correctly updated dependencies you should see the text `All dependencies match the latest package versions :)`

Comment: This worked for me flawlessly

Answer (score 5):

This problem does no longer excise with the current version of NPM (1.3.11).

Update works fine with: `npm update`

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. Here's the [thread tracking the issue](https://npm.community/t/npm-update-doesnt-save-package-json/872/6?u=dandv).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using outdated npm version it might be the problem. So before any other commands execute:

```
sudo npm install npm -g
```

or (if above doesn't work):

```
sudo npm update npm -g
```

Then **relaunch** the console (in order for changes to take effect).
Now you can check your new `npm --version` and if it is up to date execute:

```
npm update
```

or (if you prefer):

```
npm update --save-dev
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in npm 5. Here's the [thread tracking the issue](https://npm.community/t/npm-update-doesnt-save-package-json/872/6?u=dandv).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem as OP had, and found no solution, so I decided to write a Grunt plugin that will auto-update my devDependencies..

It's on Github, I'd love to get some input and collaborations in order to make it the best tool that NPM hasn't provided.

Basically it will auto-update your outdated development dependencies with a simple Grunt Task.

https://github.com/pgilad/grunt-dev-update

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is installing individual dev dependencies like this

```
npm install react-test-renderer@15.6.1 --save --only=dev
```

Comment: `npm install package-name@version --save-dev` -> `only="dev"` is not correct

Answer (score 2):

i found the answer onhttps://nodejs.dev/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version and this is working for me for all the major release as well

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm update
```

to check the outdated package use

```
npm outdated
```

Answer (score 1):

One (slow) way to do force the update, is to remove the node_modules directory, and then do `npm install` again.

This was a known bug of the `npm update` command, which has been fixed on the development branch of `npm`, see here:
https://github.com/isaacs/npm/pull/3863

It should land on the latest stable version of npm pretty soon.

Comment: In case of npm > v5 you would also need to remove `package-lock.json` to make this work, otherwise it will just install the versions listed in that lock file.

Comment: Also, this won't update `package.json` for you. Here's the [thread tracking the issue](https://npm.community/t/npm-update-doesnt-save-package-json/872/6?u=dandv).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, get out of your IDE. go to the terminal itself for the computer and run the command you want and let it install its dependencies. Worked in my case. I think having an IDE issue could also bring out such issues.