# npm check and update package if needed

Tags: node.js, teamcity, npm, karma-runner

We need to integrate Karma test runner into TeamCity and for that I'd like to give sys-engineers small script (powershell or whatever) that would:

1. pick up desired version number from some config file (I guess I can put it as a comment right in the `karma.conf.js`)
2. check if the defined version of karma runner installed in npm's global repo
3. if it's not, or the installed version is older than desired: pick up and install right version
4. run it: `karma start .\Scripts-Tests\karma.conf.js --reporters teamcity --single-run`

So my real question is: "how can one check in a script, if desired version of package installed?". Should you do the check, or it's safe to just call `npm -g install` everytime?

*I don't want to always check and install the latest available version, because other config values may become incompatible*

Comment: There is an online update/analyze tool https://pkgui.com/npm see this answer about it https://stackoverflow.com/a/76342980

Comment: `npm upgrade`... I don't know what "Team City" is, but for anyone else just using Node.js, you can run `npm upgrade`.

Answer (score 1276, accepted):

To check if any module in a project is 'old':

```
npm outdated
```

'[outdated](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated)' will check every module defined in `package.json` and see if there is a newer version in the NPM registry.

For example, say `xml2js 0.2.6` (located in `node_modules` in the current project) is outdated because a newer version exists (0.2.7). You would see:

```
xml2js@0.2.7 node_modules/xml2js current=0.2.6
```

To [update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update) all dependencies, if you are confident this is desirable:

```
npm update
```

Or, to update a single dependency such as `xml2js`:

```
npm update xml2js
```

To update `package.json` version numbers, append the `--save` flag:

```
npm update --save
```

Comment: Be careful with `npm update` especially with `npm update -g` ... it does not what most peaole expect it to do! See:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6247 and https://gist.github.com/othiym23/4ac31155da23962afd0e

Comment: @jbandi As of npm@2.6.1, `npm -g update` is safe to use again. https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6247#issuecomment-92182814

Comment: Please be aware that npm update will not update your package.json file as stated by the answer from @Erik Olson.

Comment: `As of npm@5.0.0, 'npm update' will change package.json to save the new version as the minimum required dependency` https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update.html

Comment: just did `npm update` on my npm 5.6.0 and it broke all code; luckily I backed up my files before doing that

Comment: I'll be that guy and say that while `npm update` is dumb and doesn't update your `package.json` (what re you supposed to do, find each version number somewhere in your package-lock?), `pnpm update` works exactly as expected https://pnpm.io/cli/update. Pnpm is also way faster than npm and handles global packages nicely.

Answer (score 566):

`npm outdated` will identify packages that should be updated, and `npm update <package name>` can be used to update each package. But prior to npm@5.0.0, `npm update <package name>` will not update the versions in your package.json which is an issue.

The best workflow is to:

1. Identify out of date packages with `npm outdated`
2. Update the versions in your package.json
3. Run `npm update` to install the latest versions of each package

Check out `npm-check-updates` to help with this workflow.

- Install [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.org/package/npm-check-updates) with `npm i npm-check-updates -g`
- Run `npm-check-updates` to list what packages are out of date (basically the same thing as running `npm outdated`)
- Run `npm-check-updates -u` to update all the versions in your package.json (this is the magic sauce)
- Run `npm update` as usual to install the new versions of your packages based on the updated package.json

Or more simply using `npx`, so you don't have to install anything globally:

```
npx npm-check-updates -u
npm install
```

Comment: `npm outdated` will show ALL packages.. even inside other packages.. but those won't get updated with this procedure so they will always appear.. so just use `npm-check-updates` (as you actually recommended) which only shows main packages from `package.json` ... this is relevant

Comment: With yarn this is much easier just type 'yarn upgrade'.

Comment: Why must I install an update manager to manage my package manager? Do we not agree this is silly? It should be as simple as `npm install --all-outdated` but it isn't...

Comment: You can always run `npm update --save package_name` to save the latest change to package.json.

Comment: @ADJenks because  `npm-check-updates` makes major updates, according to `semver`, which might have breaking changes, whereas `npm update` does only safe minor and patch updates. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48917961/1243247

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira I understand it's only safe to do minor patches, but eventually devs want to test the latest versions in a controlled way. There's a common need and desire to do this, as demonstrated by the existence of tools to do it, therefore  I think the function should just be built in. You don't think it should be built in? I think a flag that was named  `--force-update-max` would be very useful. If they want, they could give it a name to warn people, like how react uses "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" to set raw html. It's a bit patronizing, but it waives their liability for damages.

Comment: @ADJenks yes, I agree with you that it should be something built in, but not by default

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira Yes, I didn't say anything about making it the default option, I was suggesting to add the flag `--all-outdated` which is a flag I made up which doesn't exist. The point was that I think there should be a flag that does this. I gave it a better name in my other response to you, `--force-update-max`, but my intention was the same in my original comment. A flag to update everything to the max, that would be great.

Comment: @ADJenks yes, I agree that `--force-update-max` would be a better name because it should be clear that breaking changes may occur according to `semver`. According to `semver` major updates are not backward compatible. Although the majority of the developers disregards these specifications.

Comment: npm update <packagename> --save-dev // for dev dependencies

Comment: Running `npm update --save` after `npm outdated` doesn't save the new versions in my `package.json` file. Nor does it install them. How do I update all outdated packages and save the new versions in `package.json` file?

Comment: @ADJenks because node is a community-based framework, and some group of people are motivated and willing to develop programs that does a better work than the original package manager that is half proprietary? Don't get me wrong but I think this is dope that you have to actually install something from the manager to enhance it (call that a plugin), you can feel that the community is motivated to help each other out.

Answer (score 221):

There is also a module called [`npm-check`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check):

> npm-check
>
> Check for outdated, incorrect, and unused dependencies.

[image: screenshot of npm-check]

It also provides a convenient interactive way to update the dependencies with `npm-check -u`.

Answer (score 154):

One easy step:

`$ npm i -g npm-check-updates && ncu -u && npm i`

That is all. All of the package versions in `package.json` will be the latest major versions.

Edit:

What is happening here?

> 1. Installing a package that checks updates for you.
> 2. Use this package to update all package versions in your `package.json` (-u is short for --updateAll).
> 3. Install all of the new versions of the packages.

Comment: @imnickvaughn `ncu` stands for node-check-updates and `-a` is the 'upgradeAll' option. Find all options here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

Comment: And what if I want to do it in one line without using another package like ncu?

Comment: Or without the global install, `npx -p npm-check-updates ncu -u`

Comment: `npm-check-updates` makes major updates, according to `semver`, which might have breaking changes. Use it carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48917961/1243247

Answer (score 85):

- To update a single local package:

  1. First find out your outdated packages by:

     `npm outdated`
  2. Then update the package or packages that you want manually as:

     `npm update --save <package_name>`

This way it is not necessary to update your local `package.json`
file manually.

**Note that the above command will update your package to the latest version.**

- If you write some version in your `package.json` file and do:

  `npm update <package_name>`

  **In this case you will get just the next stable version (wanted) regarding the version that you wrote in your `package.json` file.**

And with `npm list <package_name>` you can find out the current version of your local package.

Answer (score 52):

You can try either of these options:

1. Check outdated packages

   ```sh
   npm outdated
   ```

   [image: npm outdated]
2. Check and pick packages to update

   ```sh
   npx npm-check -u
   ```

   [image: npx npm-check -u]

Answer (score 35):

No additional packages, to just check outdated and update those which are, this command will do:

`npm install $(npm outdated | cut -d' ' -f 1 | sed '1d' | xargs -I '$' echo '$@latest' | xargs echo)`

Comment: This is a great answer because it can be put in any shell script to automate this step without relying on having any further package installed.

Comment: @Jankapunkt yes, for those who have this problem, I used all the answers above with more likes but haven't solved the bug for me. in this case, this answer solved it really well! so just using this is a very great answer (tested on bash terminal)

Answer (score 27):

## NPM commands to update or fix  vulnerabilities in some dependency manifest files

- Use below command to check outdated or vulnerabilities in your node modules.

  > `npm audit`
- If any vulnerabilities  found, use below command to fix all issues.

  > `npm audit fix`
- If it doesn't work for you then try

  > `npm audit fix -f`, this command will almost fix all vulnerabilities. Some dependencies or devDependencies are locked in **package-lock.json** file, so we use `-f` flag to force update them.
- If you don't want to use force audit fix then you can manually fix your dependencies versions by changing them in **package-lock.json** and **package.json** file. Then run

`npm update && npm upgrade`

Comment: I ran `npm audit fix --force`. Now I have more vulnerabilities than before. I can run it again, but it will not change. Now what?

Answer (score 8):

When installing npm packages (both globally or locally) you can define a specific version by using the `@version` syntax to define a version to be installed.

In other words, doing:
`npm install -g karma@0.9.2` 
will ensure that only 0.9.2 is installed and won't reinstall if it already exists.

As a word of a advice, I would suggest avoiding global npm installs wherever you can. Many people don't realize that if a dependency defines a bin file, it gets installed to ./node_modules/.bin/. Often, its very easy to use that local version of an installed module that is defined in your package.json. In fact, npm scripts will add the ./node_modules/.bin onto your path.

As an example, here is a package.json that, when I run `npm install && npm test` will install the version of karma defined in my package.json, and use that version of karma (installed at node_modules/.bin/karma) when running the `test` script:

```
{
 "name": "myApp",
 "main": "app.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "karma test/*",
 },
 "dependencies": {...},
 "devDependencies": {
   "karma": "0.9.2"
 }
}
```

This gives you the benefit of your package.json defining the version of karma to use and not having to keep that config globally on your CI box.

Comment: what's in the `test` script? Can you please give me a clue how you install it with a script.

Comment: Look at the package.json. Under the "scripts" property, you can define another property, "test" whose value is a command you want to be run when you type `npm test`. npm docs are pretty good here: https://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html

Answer (score 7):

As of **npm@5.0.0+** you can simply do:

```
npm update <package name>
```

This will **automatically** update the `package.json` file. We don't have to update the latest version manually and then use `npm update <package name>`

You can still get the old behavior using

```
npm update --no-save
```

([**Reference**](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update.html))

Comment: I have `npm@7.21.1` and it is not automatically updating my `package.json`. Running `npm update <package name> --save` did not help either!

Comment: I have npm@9.5.1 and can confirm that this is not the default behavior. This is also mentioned explicitly in the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-update).

Answer (score 7):

Just do this to update everything to the latest version -
`npx npm-check-updates -u`

**Note** - You'll be prompted to install `npm-check-updates`. Press `y` and enter.

Now run `npm i`. You're good to go.

Answer (score 6):

A different approach would be to first uprade the package.json file using,

```
ncu -u
```

[image: snapshot of the terminal with the above command]
and then simply run,

```
npm install
```

to update all the packages to the latest version.
ps: It will update all the packages to the latest version however if the package is already up to date that package will not be affected at all.

Answer (score 6):

3 simple steps you can use for update all outdated packages

First, check the packages which are outdated

`sudo npm i -g npm-check-updates`

Second, put all of them in ready

`ncu -u`

Results in Terminal will be like this:

[image]

Third, just update all of them.

`npm install`

That's it.

Answer (score 5):

To really update just one package install NCU and then run it just for that package. This will bump to the real latest.

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates

ncu -f your-intended-package-name -u
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this completely automatically in 2022

1. Install [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)
2. Run the command

   ncu --doctor -u
3. It will first try every dependency you have and run tests, if the tests fail it will update each dependency one by one and run tests after each update

Answer (score 3):

If you want to upgrade a package to the latest release, (major, minor and patch), append the `@latest` keyword to the end of the package name, ex:

```bash
npm i express-mongo-sanitize@latest
```

this will update express-mongo-sanitize from *version 1.2.1* for example to *version 2.2.0*.

If you want to know which packages are outdated and which can be updated, use the `npm outdated` command

ex:

```bash
$ npm outdated
Package             Current   Wanted  Latest  Location                         Depended by
express-rate-limit    3.5.3    3.5.3   6.4.0  node_modules/express-rate-limit  apiv2
helmet               3.23.3   3.23.3   5.1.0  node_modules/helmet              apiv2
request-ip            2.2.0    2.2.0   3.3.0  node_modules/request-ip          apiv2
validator           10.11.0  10.11.0  13.7.0  node_modules/validator           apiv2
```

Answer (score 2):

One more for bash:

```
npm outdated -parseable|cut -d: -f5|xargs -L1 npm i
```

Comment: Beautiful solution! Simple and efficient! Just need to update `-f5` to `-f4` for `npm v10` in 2024

Answer (score 2):

Simple and efficient solution which doesn't require any additional dependencies and allows upgrading all packages to latest versions even if major versions changed:

```bash
npm outdated --parseable | awk -F: '{ printf("%s ", $4); }' | xargs npm install
```

Explanation:

Stage 1: `npm outdated --parseable`  Produces following output (as an example):

```
/path/to/my_app/node_modules/pakage1:pakage1@4.26.0:pakage1@4.19.2:pakage1@4.26.0:my_app
/path/to/my_app/node_modules/@pakage1/module1:@pakage1/module1@10.1.1:@pakage1/module1@10.1.1:@pakage1/module1@11.1.1:my_app
/path/to/my_app/node_modules/@pakage1/module2:@pakage1/module2@6.12.0:@pakage1/module2@6.10.2:@pakage1/module2@7.0.0:my_app
/path/to/my_app/node_modules/pakage2:pakage2@4.7.8:pakage2@4.7.7:pakage2@4.7.8:my_app
```

Stage 2: Using `awk` and specifying `:` as field separator for it, we extract the 4th fields, which contain latest versions of all packages, and combine them into single line, separating them with space: `awk -F: '{ printf("%s ", $4); }'`, produces following output:

```
pakage1@4.26.0 @pakage1/module1@11.1.1 @pakage1/module2@7.0.0 pakage2@4.7.8
```

Stage 3: Conducts single call to `npm install` with output from stage 2 used as additionaarguments: `xargs npm install` produces following command:

```bash
npm install pakage1@4.26.0 @pakage1/module1@11.1.1 @pakage1/module2@7.0.0 pakage2@4.7.8
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just interested in updating the outdated packages using the semantic versioning rules in my `package.json`.

Here's a one-liner that takes care of that

```
npm update `npm outdated | awk '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' '`
```

What it does:

1. takes the output from `npm outdated` and
2. pipes that into `awk` where we're grabbing just the name of the package (in column 1)
3. then we're using `tr` to convert newline characters into spaces
4. finally -- using backticks -- we're using the output of the preceding steps as arguments to `npm update` so we get all our needed updates in one shot.

One would think that there's a way to do this using `npm` alone, but it wasn't here when I looked, so I'm just dropping this here in case it's helpful to anyone .

** I believe there's an answer that MikeMajara provides here that does something similar, but it's appending `@latest` to the updated package name, which I'm not really interested in as a part of my regularly scheduled updates.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple projects with the same node-modules content, [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/installation) is recommended. This will prevent the modules from being downloaded in each project. After the installation the answer to your question is:

```
pnpm up
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it generally works with using `npm-check-updates` with `peer option`

**Advantages:**

- Only compatible version of packages will be updated

**Installation:**

- [Only first time] `npm install -g npm-check-updates`

**CI/CD** (First of second, working in the same manner)

- [optional] `npm i`
- [Any options is ok, both are working in the same way]

  1. `npx npm-check-updates --upgrade --peer`
  2. `ncu --peer`

[image]

[image]

P.s more detailed information can be found there https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

Answer (score -2):

You can use an online tool https://pkgui.com/npm

It edits the package.json with the major versions and allows manual changes via dropdown.

[image]