# Updated related objects in Loopback behaving inconsisently

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

When updating a related object, I get two completely different behaviors from the same code. For example, a question belongs to a student. I run the code below on two separate machines.

```
Question.observe('after save', function (ctx, next) {

   var question = ctx.instance

   question.student(function (err, student) {
      student.updateAttributes({points: student.points - question.points})
   })

next();

})
```

On the first machine it works perfectly. So I thought I was done. But then when I run the same exact code on a different machine I get the following error:

```
  student.updateAttributes({points: student.points - question.points})
                                           ^
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'points' of null
```

I am using the memory connector

```
  "db": {
     "name": "db",
     "connector": "memory",
   }
```

The only thing I an think of is that I have two different versions of loopback (one with a bug and the other one without) ... but then package.json is exactly the same for both also!?

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node .",
    "pretest": "jshint .",
    "test": "mocha"

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.5.2",
    "loopback": "^2.22.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.6.5",
    "loopback-component-explorer": "^2.1.0",
    "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^2.39.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chakram": "^1.2.1",
    "jshint": "^2.8.0",
    "loopback-testing": "^1.2.0",
    "mocha": "^2.3.4",
    "mocha-bamboo-reporter": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "description": "foo"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking for errors in `question.student`. So first you need to fix that.

Then, probably not completely related, but `question.student` is most likely asyncronous, so you are calling `next` before `question.student` is finished.

A better code would look like this

```js
Question.observe('after save', function (ctx, next) {

   var question = ctx.instance

   question.student(function (err, student) {
     if (err) return next(err);
       
     student.updateAttributes({points: student.points - question.points})
         
     next();
   });
});
```

Also, I don't know anything about `updateAttributes` but if it is async you also need to call `next()` only once it has finished (using a callback function like you did for `question.student` for example), and check for errors as well.

ALWAYS check errors. It's more than just a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Your packages.json specifies that a package should be higher than a set version, so you could have one machine where the version for `loopback` is `v2.23.0` and one at `v2.26.2` (the current latest), if you ran `npm install` at different times.

You can run `npm list` on both machines to compare the versions that are installed.

Run `npm update` to update packages.

To update your package.json to use the most up to date dependencies, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23980257/344022).

Comment: Maybe he could run `npm loopback -v` to check versions of loopback

Comment: @Overdrivr `npm list` for all dependencies (I just chose loopback as an example as they are all specified in the same way. Thanks for the comment, have added to answer.