# Update npm packages ignoring symbols like ^ and ~

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js, dependencies, package.json

I have the following dependencies in my project:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "discord.io": "^2.5.3",
    "discord.js": "^12.5.3",
    "ms": "^2.1.3",
    "node-localstorage": "^2.2.1",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0"
}
```

I wanted to upgrade these to the latest version, but if I use `npm update` the symbol `^` prevents for example the package `discord.js` to update to the version `13.1.0`. I want to ignore that symbol and force it to upgrade to the latest version.

I solved this problem by removing the package from the `package.json`, running `npm i` and then reinstalling the dependency. Is there any other possibility to do this automatically for all dependencies?

Comment: What exactly are you running in the console?

Comment: I tried `npm update`, `npm update discord.js@latest` and `npm update discord.js@13.1.0`, but nothing worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update package to a major release with NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901865/update-package-to-a-major-release-with-npm)