# How do I update Vitest via npm?

Tags: npm, vitest

I'm trying to update Vitest in my Vue project to the current version, 1.2.2. According to my `package.json` file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.38"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.3",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.2",
    "jsdom": "^20.0.0",
    "vite": "^3.0.9",
    "vitest": "^0.23.0"
  }
```

I am currently running npm version 10.1.0. According to [this page](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-update) in the npm manual, the command I should run is `npm update vitest` so that's what I ran. Then I started my tests again and it is still showing the version as V0.23.4.

Based on some of the wording on the `npm update` page, I'm guessing the problem is that the devDependencies shows Vitest as having a version number of less than 1.0.0, which somehow prevents `npm` from updating to a version of Vitest greater than 1.0.0. How do I persuade `npm` to install 1.2.2?

Comment: `npm i[nstall] vitest@1`? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/48901865/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Thank you! I drilled down in that answer to a related one - stackoverflow.com/questions/16525430/npm-check-and-update-package-if-needed/23980257#23980257- and used the workflow suggested by Erik Olson. It produced a warning and an error message but neither seem important on this trivial project. This may not be a good approach for more serious projects but it's a start so thanks again!