# Npm audit shows 9 vulnerabilities upon creating a new react native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

When I create a new React native project and I run npm audit I get 9 vulnerabilities. The list of the vulnerabilities are listed in the table below:

```
│ High          │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ ws                                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >= 1.1.5 <2.0.0 || >=3.3.1                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ react-native                                                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ react-native > react-devtools-core > ws                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/550                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ deep-extend                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=0.5.1                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ react-native                                                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ react-native > metro > jest-haste-map > sane > fsevents >    │
│               │ node-pre-gyp > rc > deep-extend                              │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/612                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ deep-extend                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=0.5.1                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ jest-expo                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ jest-expo > jest > jest-cli > jest-haste-map > sane >        │
│               │ fsevents > node-pre-gyp > rc > deep-extend                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/612                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ deep-extend                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=0.5.1                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ jest-expo                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ jest-expo > jest > jest-cli > jest-runner > jest-haste-map > │
│               │ sane > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > rc > deep-extend            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/612                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ deep-extend                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=0.5.1                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ jest-expo                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ jest-expo > jest > jest-cli > jest-runner > jest-runtime >   │
│               │ jest-haste-map > sane > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > rc >       │
│               │ deep-extend                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/612                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ deep-extend                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=0.5.1                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ jest-expo                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ jest-expo > jest > jest-cli > jest-runtime > jest-haste-map  │
│               │ > sane > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > rc > deep-extend          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/612                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Moderate      │ Prototype pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ hoek                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ react-native-scripts [dev]                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ react-native-scripts > xdl > jsonwebtoken > joi > hoek       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Moderate      │ Prototype pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ hoek                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ react-native-scripts [dev]                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ react-native-scripts > xdl > jsonwebtoken > joi > topo >     │
│               │ hoek                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.5                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ react-native                                                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ react-native > plist > xmlbuilder > lodash                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/577                       │
```

When I run `npm outdated` everything seems to be up to date.

Any help resolving these would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to run $npm list react-native, it will give you the overview where the package is used and the corresponding versions. My guess will be, those are not everywhere the latest/requiered. Hope this also will help: [npm check and update package if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525430/npm-check-and-update-package-if-needed)... The problem is the following: your packages are all up-to-date, but npm install command does not update the versions of these packages in package.json files. To do that you need to use npm-check-updates: [How do I update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version?rq=1)