# Not able to click webelement with Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Recently I have upgraded Chrome & started facing issue with Protractor tests. I am not able to click any webelement with click() function. I have to use javascript executor [browser.executeScript()] to click the webelement & it is working fine.

Current configuration I am using:
Chrome- V66
Protractor- 5.3.0
Selenium server standalone jar- 3.12.0
Chromedriver- 2.38/2.37
Jasmine- 3.1.0
Windows- 10

can anyone help me on this.

Comment: `click()` work well on my local with Chrome- 66.0.3359.139 Protractor- 5.3.0, Selenium server standalone jar- 3.12.0, Chromedriver- 2.38, Windows 10 x64.  And Chromedriver 2.38 indeed fix `Fixed element is not clickable at point` according to the change log at https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads .  Try test `click()` on other website to confirm it fail on any page or only your page.

Comment: @yong Thanks for comment. Could you please confirm version of webdriver-manager & selenium webdriver as well.

Also I have tried other sites as well but only click()is not working. Javascript executor is working fine

Comment: webdriver-manager- 12.0.6,  what's selenium webdriver? it's chromedriver?

Comment: Check your npm versions if there is any update needed. Click here for more info
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525430/npm-check-and-update-package-if-needed?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: My issue has resolved with setting  "directconnect=true".  Is there any harm with directconnect ? If yes then how can I run without directconnect.