# Command "npm update" vs package "npm-check-updates"

Tags: npm-update

What is the difference between the command [`npm update`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update) and the package [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)? Is it fully safe to use the latter?

It seems after executing `npm update` not all packages are updated, thus it seem it is incomplete. Many other [popular SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23980257/1243247) refer to use first the prior command and then the latter, but I still do not understand what the latter does that the prior does not.

Comment: npm update will update the minor versions but not major. This is explained here: https://nodejs.dev/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A bit late to the party but I felt like the previously accepted answer is outdated and slightly lacking.

### What npm Offers

[`npm update`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-update) - updates the dependencies **both** in package.json and package-lock.json in accordance to the [semantic version rules](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning) defined in `package.json`.

Key features of `npm update`:

- It will **never** update to a breaking version.
- (npm@7 and above) You can choose to update only the `package.json` file with `npm update --package-lock false`. However, this flag will completely ignore `package-lock.json` and hence automatic pruning of extraneous modules will also be disabled.
- (npm@7 and above) You can see the changes `npm update` will perform with the flag `--dry-run`, without actually updating.

[`npm outdated`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-outdated) - shows all the packages that have newer versions available, this includes breaking changes.
It prints a table that includes the package, the current version, the wanted version - according to the semver rules in the `package.json` - the latest version and the location of the package.

[image: npm outdated example]

### What npm-check-updates Offers

Running `ncu` without any flags will print a list of all the outdated packages and the version to which it would update, but will not apply any changes.

[image: Example of ncu output]

`ncu --update` - apply changes to the `package.json` file only. It will change the versions of all the dependencies in `package.json` to the latest (even if it's a breaking version!), but will not modify the `package-lock.json` file. For that, you will need to run `npm install`.

`ncu --target [patch, minor, latest, newest, greatest]` - choose which type of version to list/update.

### npm vs. ncu

| Feature | npm | ncu |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Show Outdated Packages | `npm outdated` - shows wanted & latest versions | `ncu` - shows latest by default, can be customised |
| Update Packages | `npm update` | `ncu -u` |
| Breaking Versions | Never updates to a breaking version, but shows them in `npm outdated` | Updates to and shows breaking version by default, can be customised |
| `package.json` SemVer Rules | `npm outdated` shows the "wanted" version according to SemVer rules, updates to "wanted" version | Disregards SemVer rules (unless explicitly specified), can be customised to update to different types of versions |
| Files Modified | Modifies `package.json` and `package-lock.json` and installs the updated modules | Modifies `package.json`, doesn't change `package-lock.json` and doesn't automatically install |
| Customisation | Can ignore `package-lock.json` (npm@7) and choose which packages to update | Can choose what kind of version to update to (minor, patch, latest, greatest, newest) and which packages to update |

Comment: So is there a reason why npm-check-updates does not automatically run npm install after making changes to package.json? Why would you update to the latest packages but NOT install them?

Comment: I am not the developer of this package, but I assume it's to avoid unnecessary side effects.

Comment: I think ncu filled a gap that npm didn't address, but npm > 7 addresses much of it today. NCU still does what I Want - an interactive upgrader. But currently it doesn't really support workspaces: https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates/issues/1099

and the npm outdated command does exactly that.

Comment: I believe they will add that feature if enough people request it

Answer (score 5):

`npm-check-updates` will only modify your `package.json` file. Once you've run that command, you'll then need to run a separate `npm install` to grab those changes. On the other hand, `npm update` will do all of that, and not give you the chance to check what is being updated beforehand.

There used to be an annoyance that `npm update` did not update the `package.json` file but this is no longer the case from 5.0.0. And way back when, it also looked at package dependencies which caused no end of problems for a lot of people.

The key difference between the two is that you can run `ncu` (the alias for `npm-check-updates`) and, by default, it will not update your packages - merely tell you what packages need to be updated.

For example, below is the output from one of my legacy projects. Here, you can see that a few `grunt` packages are out of date, mainly because I no longer work on this project, prefer write build scripts in npm, and haven't had the time to update older projects.

```
λ ncu
Checking D:\Github\XQSF_Master\web\package.json
[====================] 10/10 100%

 grunt                 ^1.0.3  →  ^1.0.4
 grunt-contrib-clean   ^1.0.0  →  ^2.0.0
 grunt-contrib-cssmin  ^2.2.1  →  ^3.0.0
 grunt-contrib-uglify  ^3.2.1  →  ^4.0.1
 grunt-sass            ~2.0.0  →  ~3.0.2

Run ncu -u to upgrade package.json
```

No changes to my project were made - it simply told me what needed to be updated. This is why I prefer `npm-check-updates`. By default it doesn't make any changes.

If you **DO** want changes to be made by ncu, simply run `ncu -u`. This will update your `package.json`, but you will still need to run `npm install` for the `node_modules` folder to be updated to your new packages.

Comment: are you thus saying that `ncu` is now mere informative? But I got the impression that `npm update` didn't update to the latest versions whereas `ncu` did.

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira. No, I'm not. If you run it without any arguments, then it won't actually make changes to your `package.json` file or `node_modules` folder. This has always been the default behaviour, as far as I know. If you pass `ncu -u` it will modify your package.json file (although you'll still need to run `npm install` for your `node_modules` folder to get the new packages).
**NB:** I've edited my answer to provide more information on this.

Comment: On the 1st paragraph you say `npm update` will do "all of that". What do you mean? What is the difference between `npm update` and `ncu -u && npm update`? `npm update` does not change package.json? I still don't understand.

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira `npm update` will change your `package.json` and update your `node_modules` folder.

Comment: and `ncu -u` will also change your `package.json`. So what is the difference?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira There is no difference between `ncu -u` and `npm update`, but then, that wasn't your question. Your question was the difference between `ncu` (or its full name `npm-check-updates`) and `npm update`, and there are differences here which I laid out in my answer.

Comment: thanks, I will put it as the solution, but I still get the impression that `ncu -u && npm update` does more than merely `npm update`. I think the latter keeps some inter-dependencies whilst the prior forces the update of all the packages to the latest version, but that's a "feeling".

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira If you think there's more to it then you should definitely investigate. If it turns out that I'm wrong, come back, add your findings as a new answer and mark that as accepted. That way more people will be understand the differences. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some investigation and after a lot of misinformation I think I finally got it.

`npm-check-updates` will modify your `package.json` file with the latest updates of each package, and not respecting any [npm semantic versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning), meaning that your project may break. Once you've run `npm-check-updates`, you'll then need to run a separate `npm install` to grab those changes to the latest versions.

On the other hand `npm update` updates the packages to its latest versions according to the [semantic versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning) set in the file `package.json`.

For example a major release in a dependency (an increase in the first digit in the 3 figures version) makes changes that may break backward compatibility. If you set that dependency in `package.json` with the caret symbol `^`, the command `npm install` will not make an update of a major release whereas `npm-check-updates` will. Check this 5 minutes [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kK4Meix58R4&feature=emb_logo) of npm because it is very clarifying.