# I used nvm to install the latest node.js version, but when I tried to update npm, it doesn't work

Tags: node.js, npm

I used `nvm` to install the latest node.js version, but when I tried to update to the latest `npm` version, it said this:

`npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for npm@8.6.0: wanted: {"node":"^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=16"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})`

`npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@8.6.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade your version of node.

I ran into this same issue.

If you used Homebrew run:

```
brew update  # This updates Homebrew to latest version
brew upgrade node
```

If you use nvm run:

```
nvm current node -v  # Checks your current version
nvm install <version>  # Example: nvm install 14.15.0
```

For the above step go to https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Grab a version that satisfies the conditionals in your error, the latest version should work.

More Detailed Walkthrough: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-update-node/

Comment: i already installed the **latest** nodejs using nvm

Comment: `nvm current node -v` gives me `v17.8.0` which is the latest

Comment: ok, I see then you can try to update NPM in your terminal with these commands. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525430/npm-check-and-update-package-if-needed

Comment: `ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v10.19.0`
`You'll need to upgrade to a newer Node.js version in order to use this`
`version of npm. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/`

it still thinks its on `Node.js v10.19.0`

Comment: yes, because you have to upgrade your node version to install the latest version of NPM. and the ERROR itself says that you will need to upgrade to a newer Node.js version :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `package-lock.json` before updating to the latest npm version .

Comment: did not work dude

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

nvm install NEW_VERSION --reinstall-packages-from=OLD_VERSION

Comment: `Version 'NEW_VERSION' not found - try 'nvm ls-remote' to browse available versions.`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you revise your command?

Answer (score 0):

This will install current version of node.

`nvm install node`