# How do I update a React Framework Template?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frameworks

I'm struggling to understand the theory of updating framework templates. I've used Creative Tim's Argon Node Admin template and now Benwindings's React-Admin-Firebase template.

I built apps with these frameworks awhile back and haven't touched them since. Now they won't run and have errors and warnings of deprecation.

**If I want to get these apps up and running again, is the idea to update all the dependencies? If so, how do I do that?**

I am trying to make changes to my react-admin-firebase. I haven't touched the app in about 16 months. Since then, tons of dependencies have been updated to newer versions including React itself.

The version of the react-admin-firebase template I am using has React 16, Firebase 7, etc.

How do I download and update all the dev dependencies and everything else that needs to be updated for my outdated app?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm check and update package if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525430/npm-check-and-update-package-if-needed)

Comment: @jmargolisvt I think that's definitely helpful! So is the idea to do yarn or npm outdated to your outdated app and then npm or yarn update and everything should work again?

Comment: Everything except the last part.  In theory it should all just work that way, but it rarely does.  I would carefully update each one and make sure nothing breaks as you go. Good luck!