# How do i upgrade my nightwatch from version 1.7 to the latest nightwatch version

Tags: npm, installation, upgrade, nightwatch

I have npm installed but unsure of what command to use to upgrade to v3 of nightwatch please help

i have ran 'npm install nightwatch' but it is still using the old version

New to all of this so some help is appreciated.

Thankyou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm check and update package if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525430/npm-check-and-update-package-if-needed)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to reinstall an existing dependency will result in the same version unless you explicitly specify the target version.

In the time of writing this comment the latest version is `3.4.0`
Which means you need to use the following command on your root folder or the folder path where your package.json is located:

```
npm i nightwatch@3.4.0
```