# How can I update bower.json with installed packages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, package, bower

In my project I've installed [Bower](https://bower.io/) components without the **save** option. Now, I would like update to `bower.json`.

How can I update *bower.json* with installed packages?

Comment: The lack of a one step way to do this seems like quite a deficiency. Since there's an uninstall command, it seems like running `bower install` without `--save` would always be harder and never easier.

Comment: If you have nothing in your bower.json, just remove it and type `bower init` in your console.

Answer (score 146):

Just list your dependencies:

```
bower list
```

Then you should run all install commands with parameter '--save' like this:

```
bower install bootstrap --save
```

It's a hard work, but if you have a thousand dependencies, you could create a script to automate the task.

Comment: I found this got problematic with just ~10 packages, as it's not obvious which packages were downloaded as dependencies of others, which caused bower to prompt for version numbers. Even with the correct answers, the resulting bower.json file was not quite right. I worked with Sebastien's answer, which worked for me.

Comment: The dependencies that not has declared in bower.json are identified by  "extraneous" tag on console.

Answer (score 135):

### A little trick if you don't want to write a script for that:

Before doing anything, *rename* your *bower.json* file in *bower2.json*, for example.

Then you can do a:

`bower init`

(it automatically creates a *bower.json* file).

Note that all questions should be pre-filled with your current configuration.

When it will ask you:

> set currently installed components as dependencies?

say "yes".

You now have all your dependencies in the new *bower.json* file (and you can check if everything is right with the old *bower2.json* file).

Comment: What is the registry option it mentions when doing this - I had assumed this command would be doing just a local thing. I elected to keep mine private with that handy question but would like to learn what that meant - is there some kind of internet bower registry. I am just inline thinking this is how bower might do an npm install kind of thing.

Comment: @landed : that would be the bower packages registry (http://bower.io/search/) HTH

Comment: This didn't work out for me because `bower.json` did not list `angular:'1.5.5'`.  This is because I had `angular-animate` installed and since it depends on `angular 1.5.5` bower decided not to include `angular` in the `bower.json` (considering it will install it anyways when someone does a `bower install` for this `bower.json`).  This will be an issue if someone remove `angular-animate` from `bower.json` in which case `bower` will not install `angular` too since its not listed.

Answer (score 35):

A bit arduous way is to run `bower list`, look for packages labeled *extraneous* and add those manually to the dependencies in the *bower.json* file.

If there are a lot of *extraneous* packages, it might be easier to workaround this by running `bower init` and answering *Yes* to "set currently installed components as dependencies?". This will take your current *bower.json* file, read it and then create new one using information from the old one. So in an ideal case you will have the same file just with *extraneous* packages added.

**Warning**: Firstly, there might be something lost in the process (e.g., `devDependecies`). Secondly, in the last version of Bower (v1.2.7) this will **not** preserve current packages information! I feel it is a bug. However you can save the old file and (manually) merge it with the generated one.

Also, you should ask for an option or something by [opening a Bower issue](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues) as this would be welcomed by many developers.

Comment: Note: bower 1.3.3 preserves current packages info.

Answer (score 28):

You can use [bower-check-updates](https://github.com/Light241/bower-check-updates) (you need an installed *[Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)* on your machine):

`bower-check-updates` is a utility that automatically adjusts a *bower.json* file with the latest version of all dependencies.

*bower-check-updates* is a fork of [npm-check-updates](https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates), so it's all the same, but it updates file *bower.json*, instead of file *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)*.

```
npm install -g bower-check-updates
bower-check-updates -u
bower install
```

This will install `bower-check-updates` globally, so you can launch it from anywhere.

P.S.: For more information about npm-check-updates, please see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22849716/930170)

Comment: Maybe `bower install`

Comment: @ÁmonTamás `bower install` didn't update bower.json.

Comment: The author of bower-check-updates has deprecated the project in favour of npm-check-updates, which has added support for updating bower.json.

Answer (score 2):

If there aren't that many Bower packages you have installed, try writing `bower install [package_name] --save`. This will just update your *bower.json* file.

Answer (score 0):

After `bower-check-updates -u` you must run `bower install` instead of `npm install`