# Bootstrap ParseError: Syntax Error on line 648 in mixins.less:648:25 647

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-recess

After updating to Bootstrap 3.1.0 I get this error when compiling less files:

> ParseError: Syntax Error on line 648 in mixins.less:648:25 647

```
padding-right: (@grid-gutter-width / 2); 648   &:extend(.clearfix all); 649 }
```

I use recess, version: 1.1.9. How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to update less to newer (for Bootstrap 3.1 and newer)

For those who use grunt, there's a magic

```
npm update --save
```

If problems with updating npm dependencies see [How do I update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version).

Comment: There is no newer version of recess, so why is this marked as the answer? ticcky's answer does fit more...

Answer (score 8):

If you are using grunt-recess, you need to modify it to grunt-contrib-less, [according to  the release blogpost](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2014/01/30/bootstrap-3-1-0-released/):

> We've switched from Recess to grunt-contrib-less for our compiler, giving us access to Less 1.6.x (as opposed to 1.3.x with Recess).