# .node-gyp/4.1.2/common.gypi not found

Tags: npm, gulp, ionic-framework

It correctly launches the browser emulator with `ionic serve`.

However, `gulp watch` crashes on this exception...

```
    /node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:22
    throw new Error('`libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?');
    ^

Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
```

Strangely though `npm rebuild node-sass` trips over itself with this error

```
gyp: .node-gyp/4.1.2/common.gypi not found
```

The issue was discussed here, suggests that `npm@2.14.4` fixes the issue. 
https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-native/issues/27

However, I'm running `npm@2.14.6`.

I must be overlooking something trivial here or in issue 27. Can anyone see what it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE: A similar issue can occur with `grunt-sass`.**

I fixed it by removing the version restriction from `gulp`, `gulp-sass` and reinstalling the modules:

1. Move/Remove all modules in the project's node_modules folder (the
   "locally" installed modules)
2. In `package.json`, replace the version numbers next to `gulp` and `gulp-sass` with `"*"`.
3. *(step unnecessary)* For good measure, add `node-gyp` and `node-sass` to the dependencies, also with `"*"`.
4. Run `npm install`

As a guide, you can use [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version) about updating dependencies.

**Basically you need to make sure that gulp-sass uses node-gyp + node-sass instead of pangyp.**

I wanted to start my first `node` project in a clean state so struggled with this problem for a while. Downgrading didn't work.

> The problem seemed a conflict with the forced versioning of `gulp-sass` in `package.json`. `gulp-sass` probably relied on `pangyp` instead of `node-gyp` at some point and now that `pangyp` is depreciated, it somehow causes a conflict.

I believe the versions are there to protect you, especially in production. From my experience, (which is about 1 weeks now) updating some modules a project uses is not all that risky.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can confirm setting sass version to "*" works also for grunt as it seems to be npm versioning issue.  Step 3 was not necessary.