# "npm install" gives error message "invalid", what is it?

Tags: npm, npm-install

[image]

Please check the picture.

I guess it's related to `package.json` but am not very sure.

---

**Replying to the comment for more information**

Initially I was installing `material-ui`.

The detailed messages are here:

> I:\react-boilerplate>npm install material-ui
>
> react-boilerplate@3.4.0 I:\react-boilerplate
>
> +-- material-ui@0.17.1
>
> | +-- keycode@2.1.8
>
> | +-- lodash.throttle@4.1.1
>
> | +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@^15.4.2
>
> | +-- react-addons-create-fragment@15.4.2
>
> | +-- react-addons-transition-group@15.4.2
>
> | +-- react-event-listener@0.4.3
>
> | | +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@^15.4.2
>
> | | `-- react-addons-shallow-compare@15.4.2
>
> | +-- recompose@0.22.0
>
> | | `-- change-emitter@0.1.3
>
> | `-- simple-assign@0.1.0
>
> +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-tap-event-plugin@^2.0.1
>
> `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2.2.0-rc.3

Then I was trying to fix the UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY by `npm install` them.

The first attempt gives this:

> react-boilerplate@3.4.0 I:\react-boilerplate
>
> +-- react@15.4.2  invalid
>
> +-- react-tap-event-plugin@2.0.1
>
> `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2.2.0-rc.3
>
> `-- webpack-sources@0.1.5

As you can see this is the first `invalid` I met.

So I'm just trying to figure out why this `invalid` pops out and how to fix it.

---

**Replying to the comment for more information**

Here is the package.json, dependencies section

> "dependencies": {
>       "babel-polyfill": "6.20.0",
>       "chalk": "1.1.3",
>       "compression": "1.6.2",
>       "cross-env": "3.1.3",
>       "express": "4.14.0",
>       "fontfaceobserver": "2.0.7",
>       "immutable": "3.8.1",
>       "intl": "1.2.5",
>       "invariant": "2.2.2",
>       "ip": "1.1.4",
>       "lodash": "4.17.2",
>       "minimist": "1.2.0",
>       "react": "15.4.1",
>       "react-dom": "15.4.1",
>       "react-helmet": "3.2.2",
>       "react-intl": "2.1.5",
>       "react-redux": "4.4.6",
>       "react-router": "3.0.0",
>       "react-router-redux": "4.0.6",
>       "react-router-scroll": "0.4.1",
>       "redux": "3.6.0",
>       "redux-immutable": "3.0.8",
>       "redux-saga": "0.14.0",
>       "reselect": "2.5.4",
>       "sanitize.css": "4.1.0",
>       "styled-components": "1.1.2",
>       "warning": "3.0.0",
>       "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.1"   },

and the devDependencies section

> "devDependencies": {
>       "babel-cli": "6.18.0",
>       "babel-core": "6.21.0",
>       "babel-eslint": "7.1.1",
>       "babel-loader": "6.2.10",
>       "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "1.0.0",
>       "babel-plugin-react-intl": "2.2.0",
>       "babel-plugin-react-transform": "2.0.2",
>       "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "6.18.0",
>       "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "6.9.1",
>       "babel-plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "6.8.0",
>       "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.2.11",
>       "babel-preset-latest": "6.16.0",
>       "babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
>       "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
>       "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.16.0",
>       "cheerio": "0.22.0",
>       "circular-dependency-plugin": "2.0.0",
>       "coveralls": "2.11.15",
>       "css-loader": "0.26.1",
>       "enzyme": "2.6.0",
>       "eslint": "3.11.1",
>       "eslint-config-airbnb": "13.0.0",
>       "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "10.0.1",
>       "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "0.8.0",
>       "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
>       "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.2.3",
>       "eslint-plugin-react": "6.7.1",
>       "eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "0.1.5",
>       "eventsource-polyfill": "0.9.6",
>       "exports-loader": "0.6.3",
>       "file-loader": "0.9.0",
>       "html-loader": "0.4.4",
>       "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.1",
>       "image-webpack-loader": "2.0.0",
>       "imports-loader": "0.6.5",
>       "jest-cli": "18.0.0",
>       "lint-staged": "3.2.1",
>       "ngrok": "2.2.4",
>       "node-plop": "0.5.4",
>       "null-loader": "0.1.1",
>       "offline-plugin": "4.5.2",
>       "plop": "1.7.3",
>       "pre-commit": "1.1.3",
>       "react-addons-test-utils": "15.4.1",
>       "rimraf": "2.5.4",
>       "shelljs": "0.7.5",
>       "sinon": "2.0.0-pre",
>       "style-loader": "0.13.1",
>       "url-loader": "0.5.7",
>       "webpack": "2.2.0-rc.3",
>       "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.9.0",
>       "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.15.0"   }

Comment: Can you provide more information? What else was printed to the output above and below that?

Comment: @E_net4 Hey I've added more information!

Comment: Please also include your project's package.json, or at least the registered dependencies.

Comment: @E_net4 Ok I've added the dependencies section!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An invalid dependency here suggests that an inappropriate version of a dependency package was installed. In this case, your project is requesting `webpack@2.2.0-rc3`, but version `2.2.1` was installed instead. Note that there is no caret (^) or tilde (~) in the version range, which means that `2.2.1` is not a valid match.

Another conflict happens with React, which is fixed at version `15.4.1` and should be upgraded to the version range `^15.4.2`, as required by other dependencies (such as `material-ui`).

In order to set a new version of a dependency (to upgrade/downgrade it), don't forget the respective save flag (`--save`/`-S` or `--save-dev`/`-D`).

```
npm install -S react@^15.4.2
```

Unfortunately, `react-tap-event-plugin` depends on version `2.2.0-rc3` webpack, so you should not upgrade webpack. Instead, you can call [`npm update --dev`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update) to make sure that all registered dependencies are installed with the right versions. If all else fails, a naive but effective trick is to remove the node_modules folder and install all packages from scratch.

Comment: Okay sounds great. Just want to confirm all details: the `invalid` message is suggesting a version conflict, however the conflicted dependency has still been successfully installed, is it? Like, the `devDepdencies` wants `2.2.0-rc3`, and I installed `2.2.1`, so it tells me `invalid`, but it still allows me to do so, right?

Comment: Oh and, how did you find out that `react-tap-event-plugin` depends on `2.2.0-rc3`?

Comment: Oops I think I was providing the wrong package.json content in my post, I've correct it with the correct github content, but the `devDependencies` for `webpack` is still `2.2.0-rc3`, so I think your answer is still valid.

Comment: 1. npm does not forbid you to install invalid versions of a package, if that is what you are wondering. The best thing to do once you have a package is to use `npm update` and meticulously upgrade dependencies. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33344550/1233251) other answer of mine provides some tips.
2. `react-tap-event-plugin` seems to depend on webpack@2.2.0-rc3 because it's right there in your logs. ;)
3. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error occur when doing an `npm install Path\Filename.tgz` where the filename is different on subsequent `npm install` calls than the original installation.

Specifically, on Windows OS where path\filename case doesn't matter.

For example, I installed with a folder name that had an upper case beginning character and then on subsequent calls, I was using the lower case name. This caused the package to not be installed and generated the red, `invalid` warning next to the package name.

Inspect the `package.json` and use the **exact** path and filename and see if that fixes it for you.