# Npm install gives 'invalid' error on latest react

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, package.json

I'm trying to update my react version by (copy paste from react website):

```
npm install --save react@^16.2.0 react-dom@^16.2.0
```

and I get the errors:

```
+-- react@16.2.0  invalid
`-- react-dom@16.2.0  invalid
```

They do appear into my package.json normally as:

```
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0",
```

So what does the invalid stand here for? Is there a way to log out the reason for the "invalid" error? Why is it invalid?

Comment: See this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249820/npm-install-gives-error-message-invalid-what-is-it

Comment: @VipulSingh, that doesn't really tell the cause or how to even go about searching for a fix.