# How can I update all npm packages/modules at once?

Tags: node.js, command-line, module, npm, package

I'm struggling to find a way to update all npm packages in one go, some articles suggest that package.json file should be edited where all version numbers need to be changed to `*` therefore forcing node to grab latest versions, but others state that such method is not considered good. Ideally, I want to find a command line option for this.

Comment: `npm outdated` might help you

Comment: @ExplosionPills doesn't return me anything, just new prompt to enter commands, is it doing something in the background?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202617/how-to-completely-update-all-node-js-modules-to-the-latest-version/34295664#34295664

Comment: best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16074029/6908282

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`npm outdated` is the command that you want to run to find all of the packages that are not up-to-date. You could pipe the output of `npm output -json` into a file and then iterate over the JSON to install the latest versions of the packages.

Comment: Oh good, so no easy way to do it

Answer (score 17):

One simple step:

```bash
$ npx npm-check-updates -u && npm i
```

This will set all of your packages in `package.json` to the latest version and apply the updates.

Answer (score 2):

You can try these one-liners.

Update all dependencies:

```
$ npm out --long --parseable |grep 'dependencies$' |cut -d: -f4 |xargs npm install --save
```

Update all devDependencies:

```
$ npm out --long --parseable |grep 'devDependencies$' |cut -d: -f4 |xargs npm install --save-dev
```

Keep in mind though that this is not usually a good idea as you might have to change something in the process of upgrading a package. If your project has many dependencies it is better to update them one by one or in small groups and run tests frequently.

Answer (score 2):

```
npm outdated -p | cut -d ':' -f 5 | xargs npm install
```

### Explaination

`npm outdated -p`: get a list of outdated packages and put them into parseable lines

Example line:

```
<project_path>\node_modules\<package_name>:<package_name>@<wanted_version>:<package_name>@<current_version>:<package_name>@<latest_version>:<module_name>
```

`cut -d ':' -f 5`: get the latest version
`xargs npm install`: install package by package

Answer (score 0):

For a single module you could try `npm install --save module@latest` That would change package.json too. You could write a shell script or script in nodejs to iterate though package.json and update all of the modules.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive update of all modules can performed with `npm update`:

- for *locally* installed modules: `npm update --depth 9999 --dev`
- for *globally* installed modules: `npm update --depth 9999 --dev -g`

A ready-to-use NPM-script to update all Node.js modules with all its dependencies:
[How to update all Node.js modules automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202617/how-to-update-all-node-js-modules-automatically)