# How can I update all Node.js modules automatically?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, dependency-management, package.json

During my work with the Node.js environment, I faced the issue of version maintenance of Node.js modules. I would like to be sure that all internal Node.js modules are updated.

Many of existing manuals focus just on how to update Node.js modules, but not how to *automate* such routine.

How can I update all Node.js modules automatically to the latest version?
Ideally, it should be some script, job, or task.

Comment: Declaring versions in `package.json` i believe is enough , you pretty much configure everything in there. Your question seems more similar to "maintaining an npm registry"..

Comment: Hey, it sounds like you answered your own question here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### To update all Node.js modules manually:

1. Open console with ***administrative*** permissions
2. Go to Node.js installation folder: `cd C:\Program Files\nodejs`
3. Update npm: `npm i npm@latest`
4. Go to modules folder: `cd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm`
5. Install all desired modules: `npm i %MODULE_NAME%@latest`
6. Install update manager: `npm i npm-check@latest -g`
7. Available updates for *locally* installed modules: `npm-check -u`
8. Available updates for *globally* installed modules: `npm-check -u -g`
9. Recursive update of all *locally* installed modules: `npm update --depth 9999 --dev`
10. Recursive update of all *globally* installed modules: `npm update --depth 9999 --dev -g`
11. Clear the cache: `npm cache clear --force`

---

### To update all Node.js modules automatically:

1. Create a package.json:

```json
{
    "_cmd-update-all-modules": "npm run update-all-modules",
    "scripts": {
        "create-global-node-modules-folder": "if not exist \"%appdata%\\npm\\node_modules\" mkdir %appdata%\\npm\\node_modules",
        "npm-i-g": "npm i npm@latest -g",
        "npm-check-i-g": "npm i npm-check@latest -g",
        "npm-check-u-l": "npm-check \"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\" -y",
        "npm-check-u-g": "npm-check \"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\" -y -g",
        "npm-deep-update-l": "npm update --depth 9999 --dev",
        "npm-deep-update-g": "npm update --depth 9999 --dev -g",
        "npm-cache-clear": "npm cache clear --force",
        "update-all-modules": "npm run create-global-node-modules-folder && npm run npm-i-g && npm run npm-check-i-g && npm run npm-check-u-l && npm run npm-check-u-g && npm run npm-deep-update-l && npm run npm-deep-update-g && npm run npm-cache-clear"
    }
}
```

2. Specify all desired modules to be installed in the `scripts` section
3. Make sure the folder with Node.js, e.g. `C:\Program Files\nodejs`, is added to the `PATH` through the *Environment Variables*
4. Copy package.json to the folder with Node.js from the step #3
5. Open console with the ***administrative*** permissions
6. In the console, go to the folder with package.json from the step #3
7. Execute `npm run update-all-modules`

Both of these approaches allow you keeping all Node.js modules updated to the latest version, wherever it is installed locally or globally.

To run this package.json, call `npm run update-all-modules`, stored as a hint inside of the `_cmd-update-all-modules` property.

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit more what you mean by, "To run package.json use the value of _cmd-update-all-modules property"... Use it where?

Comment: @Atticus29, I've elaborated the text, hope, now it is clear.

Answer (score 27):

You just need to run the commands below:

1. `npm install -g npm-check-updates`
2. `ncu -u`
3. `npm update`
4. `npm install`

**Explanations:**

1. To update all packages to new major versions, install the npm-check-updates package globally.
2. This will upgrade all the versions in the package.json file, of dependencies and devDependencies, so npm can install the new major versions.
3. You are now ready to run the update.
4. Now install updated packages. 
   The flag *--force* is sometimes required if there already exist some conflicting packages.

Reference:

*[Update all the Node.js dependencies to their latest version](https://web.archive.org/web/20220522202053/https://nodejs.dev/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version/)*

Or more simply using npx it becomes two commands and you don't install any global package:

```
npx npm-check-updates -u
npm install
```

Answer (score -4):

I went to https://nodejs.org/en/download/, downloaded the installer and repaired the installation. All warnings and errors disappeared.