# npm: Get fixed dependency versions in package.json without npm-shrinkwrap.json

Tags: npm

I want to write fixed dependency versions in my package.json of the installed (!= latest available) modules.

These are alternative solutions, which does not satisfy me requirements:

1. [Writing the **latest** available versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version) to the package.json.
2. npm shrinkwrap writes the dependencies to npm-shrinkwrap.json 
   instead of package.json

I don't want to use shrinkwrap because it's just another tool and additional configuration file for a problem which could be solved without.
Or could shrinkwrap be tweaked to write all versions from npm-shrinkwrap.json to package.json ?

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a script, which extracts the versions from the shrinkwrap file in package.json syntax:

```
node
var sw = require('/path/to/npm-shrinkwrap.json');
for (var key in sw.dependencies) { console.log('"' + key + '": "' + sw.dependencies[key].version + '",') }
```

But it's ugly and not working for dev dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

As the dependencies of your dependencies will also get updates that strategy is not bullet prove. Its better to use npm 5 with https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks shrinkwrap or yarn which has https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarn-lock/