# Using npm package.json file to get latest version and getting the plugin naming right

Tags: jquery, json, node.js

I am new to NPM and I have a beginner question. I was going through an article and came across the following of what the author has to say:

Instead of doing:

```
$ cd /path/to/the/project
$ npm install mongoose
$ npm install express
$ npm install jade
```

Create a `package.json` file in the root of your app dir.

```
$ cd /path/to/the/project
$ touch package.json
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "your app name"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": true
  , "dependencies": {
      "express": ">=2.5.0"
    , "jade": ">= 0.16.4"
    , "mongoose": ">=2.3.10"
  }
}
```

Then type in the following command all your packages will be installed.

```
$ npm install -l
```

### Difficulty

Now I really like the idea of doing the following:

```
{
    "name": "your app name"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": true
  , "dependencies": {
      "express": ">=2.5.0"
    , "jade": ">= 0.16.4"
    , "mongoose": ">=2.3.10"
  }
}
```

But what if instead of saying `">=2.5.0"`, I want it it be the latest version ? I.E. I want the same version as when I would go to the Git directory and press the download button. secondly, how do I know the specific name of the package on npm. Eg if I check the slider plugin [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slider), I see the command to install it is:

```
npm install slider
```

So does that mean that if I was installing the above plugin using package.json, my package.json would look like below:

```
{
        "name": "your app name"
      , "version": "0.0.1"
      , "private": true
      , "dependencies": {
          "slider": "whatever"  // is this correct ??
      }
    }
```

My questions are:

- how do I get the latest current stable version of a jQuery plugin
- how do I get the naming right for the package.json file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the name after the `npm install` (or in the URL) is the same as one used in the `package.json`.

If you want to find the latest versions of packages you have installed, you can use [`npm outdated`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated) which will list the latest versions of outdated libraries. Then, you can update the package.json manually or use [npm-check-updates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22849716/160386).

If you are installing a new dependency, you can use [`npm install package --save`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) which will install the latest version of the package and add it to your `package.json` automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `*` as version, like this:

```
{
    "name": "your app name"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": true
  , "dependencies": {
      "slider": "*"
  }
}
```

Edit:
As noted in the comments, this is not a very good idea, it is better to state dependencies as "^1.2.3" (will match 1.x) or even better -  "~1.2.3" (will match 1.2.x).

Comment: Using "*" (or ">=0.0.0") is generally not a good idea because if the library introduces incompatible changes, your project might break.

Comment: @JanTojnar ok ! i agree with what your saying ... so in that case what if i want to find what is the latest version of waypoints ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/waypoints  .. how do i find whats the latest version of a plugin, wihtout going to "google" and navigating to the projects git repo..

Comment: If you are adding a new dependency use `npm install package --save`, if you just want to update already installed libraries, look into `npm outdated`.

Comment: @JanTojnar npm install package --save will save the current version ... what i want is suppose i want to install a plugin waypoints.js before i even do `npm install package --save` , i'd like to know whats the lastes version .. how do i find that out from the CMD ??

Comment: @Alexander Solonik There is [`npm info package`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view)

Comment: @JanTojnar  superb , add that as a note in your answer :)

Comment: @Alexander Solonik However `npm install package --save` already does install the latest version in addition to adding it to the `package.json`

Comment: So `npm info` should not be needed when installing a new dependency nor when updating the old ones.