# Use latest major version

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

In my JavaScript applications I may be declaring a few dozen dependencies in my `package.json` file.

It would take a while to go through each one of those dependencies and see which version they are on.

I just want to say: use the latest major version, but not the bleeding edge.

As an example, with a tool like Git I don't usually care about taking changes at the patch-level but if a new major release comes out I will want it.

Is there a similar concept when specifying the version of a npm module?

Comment: The "bleeding edge" is usually a bunch of bug fixes you probably want to have.

Comment: @ceejayoz This is probably just my ignorance of the landscape, but how is that different than other tools like source control tools or browsers where I don't usually care (or want) things at the bleeding edge?

Comment: Another example is a module like `grunt`. I just want a stable version, not the bleeding edge which (I perceive) to not be as stable yet?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version

Note that this assumes the bleeding edge version is not the one listed on NPM.

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink NPM packages are *supposed* to use [SemVer](http://semver.org/) (plenty don't use it correctly, but that's the ideal). Under SemVer, versions are X.Y.Z, where X is major breaking changes, Y is new but backwards-compatible functionality, and Z is bugfixes. As such, if you're willing to be on 2.0.0, you're probably best being on 2.*.* as it'll include the latest bug fixes - *increasing* stability in general. The least stable version is going to be a brand new major version, IMO.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks...I'm starting to understand the philosophy now. So, does that mean that a recommended approach would be to always specify "*" since that's the latest?

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink `*` is not good, as a new major version (by definition) breaks things - you don't want your app going from 2.* to 3.* unexpectedly. If you do `npm install --save <package>` it'll use a version string along the lines of `^2.9.3`, which means "anything in the 2.* range that's 2.9.3 or higher". You'll get bugfixes and non-breaking feature updates, but no "oh shit, everything broke when they went to 3.0.0".

Comment: @ceejayoz Gotcha, so basically, as a responsible consumer I need to at least be aware of which major version each of the modules I am using is at. I suppose this isn't as bad as it sounds because if I use `--save` when I first download the module it will insert the major version for me. If this is correct, please summarize your points in an answer so I can upvote!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NPM packages (theoretically) use [SemVer](http://semver.org/).

In SemVer, packages get a version number of `X.Y.Z`.

`Z` indicates bug fixes. `Y` indicates new features without changing existing ones. `X` indicates a major version that breaks backwards-compatibility.

Doing `npm install --save <package>` will result in a version string in your `package.json` like `^2.3.9`, which means "anything in the `2.*` range greater than or equal to `2.3.9`". This'll mean you get bug fixes and non-breaking new features, but you won't unexpectedly be updated to a version 3.0.0 that breaks your application.

<sup>Note: I say "theoretically" because not everyone sticks to SemVer's ideal. You may find a `2.3.9 -> 2.3.10` upgrade that breaks stuff at times. Tests are handy here.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Using **`npm i -S <pkg>`** should normally do the right thing.

A few caveats:

- The above assumes if you are taking a runtime dependency on `<pkg>`.  In installing a developer tool (like `grunt`) use **`-D`** or **`-G`** instead of **`-S`**.
- [Semantic versioning rule 9](http://semver.org/#spec-item-9) says that publishers MAY identify pre-release versions using a suffix like `-beta`.  Npm depends on it, so if package publisher *FAILS* to do it, you might take a dependency on a pre-release package without knowing it.   Sophisticated npm publishers should know better, and sophisticated npm consumers should check the documentation.
- A major version is '**0**' indicates the package is still in initial development, and the package SHOULD NOT be considered stable.  ([Semantic versioning rule 4](http://semver.org/#spec-item-4).)
- Consider using **`npm dist-tag ls <pkg>`** to see if there is some package-specific tag that identifies your intent better than `latest`.  If so, use **`npm I -S <pkg>@<tag>`** to track that tag.

You can always use **`npm outdated`** to check if you dependend directly on a package with a new major release might want to consider upgrading to.   It is by-design that major version upgrades do not happen automatically.

[npm-install](/questions/tagged/npm-install)[npm-dist-tag](/questions/tagged/npm-dist-tag)[semantic-versioning](/questions/tagged/semantic-versioning)

Comment: The `npm` package itself uses `dist-tag`s tags to good effect, to see this type **`npm dist-tag ls npm`**.   If this doesn't work, upgrade to the `latest` (stable) build of npm by typing **`npm i -G npm`**.