# Node.js UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY with angular core and angular http

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Im really really new to node and im running into a few issues that i cant seem to solve.

Im trying to install a package but im getting the following errors returned

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.3
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.3

npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.1.18 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.1.18 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
```

Im guessing that means that i currently have core@2.0.0-rc.3 and http@2.0.0-rc.3 and i need rc.4

How do i go about updating them?

Any help would be fantastic.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change in you package manager ang run `npm i`
or add this to your dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
  "dep1": "^1.1.1"
}
```

^ this will update the latest package for you with `npm update`

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
```

[read this post too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version)

Comment: Nice, that worked :) Thank you so much, been trying to solve this for ages now

Comment: please if worked also accept answer that will help others :-)

Comment: I spoke too soon haha .. My application now isnt showing .... Is there a place where error logs are written or is it written on an application basis?

Comment: look into console what error are you getting? [here is my ng2 repo with webpack if it helps](https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed)

Comment: My bad .... I left a comma on the end of the package.... its been a long day hahaha thank you once again, its working perfect and is showing my app ... much respect