# angular 2 - upgrade to rc 6 from rc 5

Tags: angular, npm

What needs to be done to upgrade from RC5 to RC6? I don't mean application code changes. I'm not that far in the process yet. I mean how do I install RC 6?

I have found this [image in this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/50ndl5/upgrading_from_angular_2_rc5_to_rc6/).

I have changed my package.json to be like that image. Then I am guessing I need to run a terminal command that will install the things in my package.json? Somthing like `npm install`? Here is my code:

```
    {
  "name": "the-vegan-repository",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "lite-server-test": "lite-server --config=liteserver-test-config.json",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite-server-test\" ",
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"sass --watch app\" \"sass --watch index.scss\" \"sass --watch global-constants.scss\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.13.0",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "angular2-modal": "^1.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "jquery": "v3.1.0",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.7.0",
    "ng2-popover": "0.0.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "codelyzer": "0.0.26",
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "tslint": "^3.13.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Go for `2.0.1` its not longer in rc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your package.json is right you'll want to delete the node_modules directory and run `npm install` to download only the new packages.  That way you'll know if you missed something.

Now that angular 2.0.1 is out you can check the Tower of Heroes demo on angular.io https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/ or update the version to '*' for all of the packages you want the latest of and run `npm update --save` to replace them with the absolute latest versions per this answer. [How do I update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [the QuickStart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) to replace what you have now.