# Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-minify-css'

Tags: gulp

In fact, the module gulp-minify-css installed long ago, only the version is outdated.

This error crashes if new versions of installed modules. After the upgrade(re-installation) of the specified module everything works fine. Only if the modules of more than 10 pieces, have them update every. Tell me how to update everything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use bellow commands (I have used in Ubuntu)

```
sudo npm install gulp-minify-css
```

important :

```
sudo npm install 'modules to be install'
```