# NPM Update - Forcing Package Upgrades (Ignoring SemVer)

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-update

Is there a reasonable way to force an update on a node package?

It's great that we are protected from aggressive package development, but it seems like most package versions get saved as exact (i.e. the invisible `=`, rather than with an inequality or `^` or `~`) version numbers, so upgrading even to a patch version seems laborious.

I'm actually not getting `npm update` to work for me at all.

For example, I have, in my `package.json`, a package (let's say `dependencypackage`) listed as such:
`"dependencypackage":"^0.5.1"`, and the latest version of `dependencypackage` on www.npmjs.com is 0.7.1.

Unless I'm mistaken, according to the [doc for update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update), I should be able to run `npm update --save dependencypackage` to update the package both in the `./node_modules` directory, and in the package.json listing.

Unfortunately, this is not working for me. I get no information or output from the command.

Additional info:

- node version: 6.11.2
- npm version: 5.3.0

Example of an unreasonable solution:

- remove and reinstall each package by hand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version)

Answer (score 15):

In order to accomplish that I use [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check)

```sh
npm i -g npm-check
npm-check -u
```

And, if you have outdated dependencies, you'll get something like this
[image]

You can then sell the ones you want to upgrade and hit enter. It works like a charm.

Comment: One-liner that doesn't pollute global namespace: `npx --yes npm-check -u`