# How to do NPM Package Upgrade using Package.JSON?

Tags: node.js, npm

We are migrating couple of years old project to latest one. Package.JSON refers to older version of packages.

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0"
```

Is there any mechanism we can put `@latest` to each version and then execute NPM Update?

```
"@angular/animations": "@latest",
"@angular/cdk": "@latest",
"@angular/common": "@latest",
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version)

Answer (score 1):

You can change each to `"*"` and delete the node_modules folder and do `npm install`.

You should be prepared to fix breaking changes from multiple packages at the same time.

Normally, you should do **one at a time**, so it is easier to trace breakages and so you know at least what caused it.

If you attempt this, you should make sure you change the versions back to `"^X.X.X"` in the package.json file. Auto-updating to latest can and will definitely break things over time.