# How to npm install and force latest version (permanently)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am deploying a private npm module for internal use at our company. Since the module is handled internally, we can trust version bumps etc.

How can I install the module in various projects so that the latest version of the module will always be installed with every single `npm install`, so that I don't have to go through a bunch of projects and update the version inside each `package.json` every time we deploy?

Please note that this should *only* be for selected packages, not all packages - i.e. only those hosted on our private server.

Comment: Hi @Steveland83. I don't think it's a duplicate. I don't want to manually update each dep, I simply want to automatically install the latest release of that dep on each `npm install`.

Comment: Setting the version to "*" works for me, when I want to use the latest for private repos.  For example: ```"async": "*"```.  --EDIT-- made a formal answer below...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use "*" as your version in your package.json file.  For example:

```
"dependencies": {
 "my-awesome-repo": "*"
}
```

Upon `npm install` this will automatically install the latest version for "my-awesome-repo" that is availabile on npm.

Comment: Great, this is the solution I was looking for. Any idea how this behaves in the context of yarn.lock or npm lockfiles?

Comment: I don't know - I haven't used yarn and never pay attention to npm lockfiles.

Comment: @johnmaccarthy if you have a `yarn.lock` file that already contains the package, running `yarn` will *not* update the package to the latest. If you remove your `yarn.lock` file then it will update the package to the latest.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to run this before each install.

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
npm-check-updates -u
npm install
```

On npm < 3.11:

```
"dependencies": {
 "express": "~3.2.0",
 "mongodb": "~1.2.14",
 "underscore": "~1.4.4",
 "rjs": "~2.10.0",
 "jade": "~0.29.0",
 "async": "~0.2.7"
}
```

Comment: Cannot flag, but was answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version

Comment: But... this is not an appropriate answer at all. I _don't_ want to update all my deps, that would certainly break builds. I just want to update specific private modules in a separate @example namespace.

Comment: My understanding is that this is sadly the only ways to do it, please let us know if anything better comes up.

Comment: Feel free to check the accepted answer for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the following package, which allows version selection by dist tag rather than a semantic version (e.g. `latest`).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-json