# react update npm package

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a react project and I want to update this outdated package

```
   npm outdated
   Package                           Current           Wanted  Latest  
   Location
   native-base                         2.3.1            2.4.3   2.4.3  
   react                     16.0.0-alpha.12           16.3.2  16.3.2  
   expo                               20.1.2           20.1.4  27.0.1  
   jest-expo                          20.0.0           20.0.0  27.0.1  
   react-native                       0.47.2           0.47.2  0.55.3  
   react-native-calendars             1.14.2           1.19.3  1.19.3  
   react-native-collapsible            0.9.0            0.9.0  0.11.2  
   react-native-datepicker             1.6.0            1.7.2   1.7.2
```

First question, what is the difference between "Current" and "Wanted"?And, exactly, what I have to do? If I do "npm update", the result is:

```
npm WARN react-native@0.47.2 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.12 but 
none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-elements@0.16.0 requires a peer of react-native- 
vector-icons@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-svg@5.3.0 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.12 
but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view@0.5.0 requires a peer of 
react-native@>=0.48.4 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
```

And I do not understand if npm has updated something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated)

**Current**: The current version that you are having.

**Wanted**: is the maximum version of the package that satisfies the `semver` range specified in `package.json`.If there's no `semver` range 
 available  then wanted shows the *currently-installed* version, where `semver` means *single major version, major version or minor version*. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver).

`npm update` will install the packages to the `latest version` **respecting semver** and also modify the `package.json`.

> This means that if you have a package version **1.0.2** whose latest version is **3.0.2**, then it'll respect `semver` and upgrade it to latest `minor` version only.

For this you may either make a script to remove `node_modules` and `reinstall` them to latest as mentioned [here](https://medium.com/@jh3y/how-to-update-all-npm-packages-in-your-project-at-once-17a8981860ea) or use `npm-check-updates` as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16074029/6606831)

For upgrading major packages this approach is **not recommended** since *some libraries may or may not be compatible with the latest version of other libraries which they use as a dependency*.

Ideally you should upgrade your `react-native` version using `react-native-git-upgrade` as mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html) and then update all the dependencies