# How do I upgrade kleur@2.0.2 to kleur3

Tags: react-native, expo

I am setting up a react native project using expo init. I selected expo-template-tab. However, I am getting this error

```
npm WARN deprecated kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit <https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0\> for migration path(s).
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --depth=1 -q -b v0.22.1-exp.0 git://github.com/expo/react-native-maps.git /home/osborne/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-9261e1d2
npm ERR! /home/osborne/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-9261e1d2/.git: Permission denied
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/osborne/.npm/_logs/2019-03-23T23_10_23_777Z-debug.log
Process exited with non-zero code: 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the package or did you tried upgrade upgrade like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version

Comment: Still not working