# How can I update all Angular dependencies?

Tags: angular-cli

I want to update all my angular dependecies but whatever I did, I could not manage to update.

```
Package                                   Current  Wanted  Latest
@angular/animations                        5.2.11  5.2.11  7.2.15
ckoffice
@angular/cdk                                5.2.5   5.2.5   7.3.7
ckoffice
@angular/cli                                1.7.4   1.7.4   7.3.9
ckoffice
@angular/common                            5.2.11  5.2.11  7.2.15
ckoffice
@angular/compiler                          5.2.11  5.2.11  7.2.15
ckoffice
@angular/compiler-cli                      5.2.11  5.2.11  7.2.15
ckoffice
@angular/core                              5.2.11  5.2.11  7.2.15
ckoffice
@angular/forms                             5.2.11  5.2.11  7.2.15
```

`ng` command is not working unfortunatelly, how can I update without `ng` commad? I read millions of document but nothing works for me.
ng command is not working unfortunatelly, how can I update without `ng` commad? I read millions of document but nothing works for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-to-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `npm-check-updates` is the only way to make this happen now.

This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16074029/16298287) might help

Answer (score 0):

You should run `ng update` command with `--all` option will attempt to update all packages in `package.json` file.

However, the caveat (which seems to apply also to your case) is that it won't proceed if it discovers that some package inter-dependencies are not met.
One way to proceed anyways, is to add `--force` option.

Answer (score 0):

for me `npm update --all --save` worked.