# Updating all packages with Npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I have a fairly large number of packages that are outdated and I want to update. I tried running npm update as described in the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update#description): `npm update --depth 9999 -dev`
The update took a long time and at the end it failed. I tried a few more time, I set the stack size to unlimited, etc, but it always takes hours and at the end it fails.

I tried updating a single package with --depth 999 (not 9999) and that failed as well.

Is there any recommended way how to update all packages that works?

```
**Edit:** At first I was getting  `MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit`
```

Then I got a heap exceeded exception:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

And finally, I got `Max call stack size exceeded.`

I set the stack size to unlimited and lowered the depth, but it's been running for hours with no result.

Comment: The `--depth` parameter is for recursively updating packages, and may not be what you want (i.e. let package creators deal with which version *they* install while updating all of the direct top level packages).

Comment: What error is shown when it fails?

Comment: What do you mean with update? Change `package.json` to last version of packages? Or just update `node_modules`?

Comment: If these are globally installed, you may want to consider moving away from global installs to directory-level installs.

Comment: @Rashomon. Both.

Comment: @WillCain No, they are all local

Comment: If you are using VSCode I highly recomend this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pflannery.vscode-versionlens. You can check easily what version is installed and whats the last version

Comment: A `npm install` automatically updates the installed packages to last one (if you spicified the version with "^"). Not sure if exists a method to update the number on `package.json` (the previous suggested extension does it)

Comment: @Rashomon Not, VS, I'm running command line on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rashomon I saw that but didn't notice the update so I assumed it's out of date (the question is 6 years old). Michael Cole's answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30607722/2036161 is kind of what I was trying but the --depth flag threw me off.

Comment: https://medium.com/@jh3y/how-to-update-all-npm-packages-in-your-project-at-once-17a8981860ea

this is the best solution I've found so far

Answer (score 4):

It turns out I somehow had 4 npm update jobs running. I killed them, then ran `npm outdated`, took the output and ran `npm install <package>@<version>` for each package.

For good measure I then installed and ran `npm-check-udates` which installed another handful of packages.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
npm cache clean
```

and try again.

Comment: This is worded like a question, not an answer.  If you know this to be the answer, maybe just say "Run `npm cache clean` and try again."

Comment: @Wyck I've edited that - it was clearly an attempt to answer the question, but bad formatted.

Comment: I'll try that. I feel that the failed update attempt (and a couple I terminated early) are affecting things, so it's possible clearing the cache could help.

Comment: this does not work since npm@5, you need to: `npm cache clean --force` and then `npm outdated`