# npm outdated doesn't show anything but version numbers in package.json are outdated

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I ran these commands to upgrade all my npm packages (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version)):

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

When I do `npm outdated` now, nothing comes up (it did before). However, my package.json didn't change at all. I want the package.json to reflect my changes. How do I do that?

Comment: You could also use [`npm update`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update.html). However, `ncu -u` should also update the package.json.

Comment: `npm outdated` would not change the `package.json` it just lists outdated packages if at all. **why is it not showing anything?**: Because you updated them with `ncu -u` which does update the `package.json` and `npm install` would install em actually reading `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my mistake, I was actually looking at the wrong package.json.