# Why npm-update does not install all the packages to the their respective latest version?

Tags: npm, npm-update, npm-check-updates

I've searched other questions but I need a clear canonical answer, since it's not yet clear for me why the command `npm update` does not install each package to the latest version, and thus we need an extra package, such as [`npm-check-updates`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version) to be installed globally.

- Is it fully safe to forcibly update all the packages to each of the respective latest version?
- Why the command `npm update` does not do it? Package versions dependencies problems?