# Npm: How can I solve dependecies which has no intersection of required version?

Tags: npm, dependencies, eslint

My issue is pretty simple but I'm not so good with npm. I have tried to update dependencies of a Nuxt.js project by using the commands exposed on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version) thread which worked fine to update my **package.json** with the latest packages.

However, by running the command `npm list --depth=0` to check if there were any issues, I had the following problem with @eslint library.

The result is the following (with `eslint@7.0.0`):

> ```
> `-- vuetify-loader@1.4.4
>
> npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint@^2 || ^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7.2.0, required by eslint-plugin-import@2.21.1
> npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0, required by eslint-plugin-vue@6.2.2
> npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint@2.x - 6.x, required by eslint-plugin-import@2.19.1
> npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0, required by eslint-plugin-vue@6.2.2
> npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint@^6.4.0, required by eslint-template-visitor@1.1.0
> npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0, required by eslint-plugin-vue@6.2.2
> PS C:\Projects\Sponsor.Online\sponsr\frontendr>
> ```

As you can see, seems that it can be solved by installing `eslint@6.4.0`, but as soon as I do so, the result is the next one:

> ```
> `-- vuetify-loader@1.4.4
>
> npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint@^7.0.0, required by @nuxtjs/eslint-config@3.0.0
> npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint@>=6.8.0, required by eslint-plugin-unicorn@19.0.1
> PS C:\Projects\Sponsor.Online\sponsr\frontendr>
> ```

Seems that I have no easy way to solve these dependencies since some of them required a version up to version 6.0.0 and others required version above 7.0.0

What options do I have?

- Can I have two version of the same package? It's ok to do so?
- Should I consider removing some of these packages?
- Should I downgrade some packages manually and see how I can intersect those versions?

Answer (score 1):

Just install `eslint@latests` and if everything works either ignore the warnings, or if it really bugs you make PR requests on the packages that have not been updated to reflect that they work ok with latest version of esLint. It should just be a case updating one line in each projects `package.json` file.