# Yarn - How do I update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I have a react app with deprecated dependencies. To make it work, I have to update the dependencies to their newer (but stable) versions.

As per [this stakoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version) thread, to update dependencies in package.json to latest versions, [npm-check-updates](https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates) is the Best Option for npm. However, I'm using yarn for package management. Is there an equivalent of npm-check-updates in yarn. So that, I use a single package manager to manage my dependencies.

Comment: [npm-check-updates](https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates) is fully compatible with yarn. Just run `npx npm-check-updates` in your project directory.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

`yarn upgrade-interactive --latest`

But you have to have a `yarn.lock` file before do it. If you are using `npm`, you must delete `package-lock.json` first. Then run `yarn` to create structure. After that you can do `upgrade-interactive`. Without that, `yarn` shows upgrade, but no changes and effects in `package.json`.

Comment: Clear your ```node_modules``` folder and ```yarn.lock``` , ```yarn-error.log``` files. Then try ```yarn --ignore-engines```. After successful instllations, try ```yarn upgrade-interactive --latest```.

Comment: If all of these had no success, then try ```yarn outdated``` and update packages directly manual in ```package.json``` one by one. You need to have relaxed mind before do that :)

Comment: Loved the `yarn outdated` as this seems more logical to do if got a long list of deps :)

Comment: It's `yarn up` for the modern version of Yarn https://yarnpkg.com/cli/up

Comment: this inexplicably doesn't upgrade some packages. `npx npm-check-updates` seems to be the better solution.

Comment: 'yarn upgrade-interactive --latest'
Unknown Syntax Error: Unsupported option name ("--latest").

Comment: Running this doesn't update my package.json

Comment: Running this doesn't update my package.json

Comment: @olawalejuwonm
have you tried ```yarn ignore-engines``` at first to create the initial valid ```yarn.lock``` file before the upgrade?

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi i already have a yarn.lock

Comment: @olawalejuwonm remove ```node_modules```, ```yarn.lock``` and try ```yarn ignore-engines```. upgrade-interactive would work after that.

Comment: How can I store the upgraded versions in `package.json`? I see that the packages in `yarn.lock` got upgraded.

Answer (score 90):

You can upgrade a single package to the latest major version with this:

```
yarn upgrade <package-name> --latest
```

Comment: You want him to go one by one and list all his packages?

Comment: Sometimes you want to only update a single dependency. For updating the patch version (major.minor.patch), you can use e.g. yarn upgrade <package-name>@1.1.x (use whatever major/minor version you have)

Comment: @zmx is the best answer in this page. Upgrading an entire dependency may end up in a rabbit hole, and unfortunately the other suggestions don't always work.

Comment: This answer is wrong--this command does not update the package.json with the latest version.

Comment: you can also use `--pattern="<pattern>"` instead of `<package-name>`

Comment: This doesn't upgrade the major version.

Comment: npx npm-check-updates works just fine

Answer (score 56):

You can try this npm package [`yarn-upgrade-all`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-upgrade-all). This package will remove every package in `package.json` and add it again which will update it to latest version.

installation:

```bash
npm install -g yarn-upgrade-all
```

usage:
in your project directory run:

```bash
yarn-upgrade-all
```

Comment: Thanks! Its a good option with only one caution. From official docs "Don't use yarn to install it on Windows because there is a bug https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2224"

Comment: This package runs `yarn remove && yarn add` for all packages in `package.json`
Too slow, but works!

Shorter version: 
`npx yarn-upgrade-all`

Comment: `yarn yarn-upgrade-all` didn't work for me but `npx yarn-upgrade-all` worked. Thanks @AndrewZolotarev

Comment: Running `npx yarn-upgrade-all` changed my `"vue": "^3.0.5"` dependency to `"vue": "^2.6.14"` which I did not expect. Obviously, this broke the build.

Comment: `npx yarn-upgrade-all`

Comment: He specifically said "newer (but *stable*) versions", which this does not - the result is similar to `yarn upgrade --latest`, which will also install breaking changes. I have not seen any command or tool that does what OP asked for.

Answer (score 24):

The one that worked for me is from [a comment by @Andrew Zolotarev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650640/yarn-how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version/68658527#comment116531067_62801156), which uses

```
npx yarn-upgrade-all
```

Comment: For now I use `npx npm-upgrade`.
I think it's better in usage for me.

Answer (score 24):

## With Yarn v2 and v3 (Berry)

You have to install appropriate plugin first with:

```
yarn plugin import interactive-tools
```

and then execute

```
yarn upgrade-interactive
```

Source: https://yarnpkg.com/cli/upgrade-interactive

Answer (score 12):

## List outdated

```bash
yarn outdated
```

## Upgrade all dependencies to latest

This will upgrade to the latest version, irrespective of if the package is stable or the versioning constraints between your packages.

```bash
yarn upgrade --latest
```

[Yarn docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/)

Comment: This will install *unstable* versions - not what OP asked for.

Answer (score 12):

[npm-check-updates](https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates) is fully compatible with yarn. Just run `npx npm-check-updates` in your project directory.

`npm-check-updates` is a battle-tested, 8yr old library that *just works*. It offers interactive mode and doctor mode for automatically running tests and identifying broken upgrades.

**Disclaimer: I am the main contributor of npm-check-updates.**

[image: npm-check-updates - default output]

Interactive + Group mode:

[image: npm-check-updates - interactive mode]

Comment: Why not: `yarn upgrade --latest` without needing to bother with an additional package installation

Comment: @Eugene because no one understands what "yarn upgrade --latest" actually does.  For example, I have "hardhat": "^2.9.5" in my package.json, and would expect yarn upgrade --latest to change that to 2.10.1.  But no.  (It's probably a flag somewhere, may caret?  Don't know, don't care.) It did update other things though.  ncu just does the sensible thing.

Comment: You should definitely try this great package `npm-check-updates` ⬆️

Answer (score 7):

If you want to update packages with yarn and update the package.json accordingly,

1. Install syncyarnlock -  `yarn global add syncyarnlock`
2. Update packages - `yarn upgrade` or `yarn upgrade --latest`
3. Sync updated versions of yarn.lock to package.json - `syncyarnlock -s`

Comment: note that you will need to run `yarn install` again as the last step - it won't do anything other than update `yarn.lock` again, but if you don't do this, `yarn` will complain later that the version constraints that were *used* when `yarn.lock` was generated are now out of date.

Answer (score 4):

In case you wanted to add the package to your package.json for development collaboration

```
yarn add yarn-upgrade-all -D
```

```
yarn yarn-upgrade-all
```

By the way, the package uses the command ( reinstall all packages again )

```
yarn install package1 package2 packageN
```

Answer (score 4):

Update dependencies to latest versions, using jq:

```
jq '.dependencies | keys | .[]' package.json | xargs yarn add
```

Update dev dependencies to latest versions:

```
jq '.devDependencies | keys | .[]' package.json | xargs yarn add --dev
```

Answer (score 1):

If none of the answers worked for you, try to install again:

```
yarn add {PACKAGENAME HERE}
```

it will overwrite the current version to the latest version available

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `--ignore-engines` flag. So package installation will not fail due to an incompatible node version.

First run:

```
yarn --ignore-engines 
// This will install the older packages
```

And then:

```
yarn upgrade --ignore-engines 
// This will update packages to latest
```