# How to automatically update version information to latest for all dependencies in flutter pubspec

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an existing flutter pubspec file with a lot of dependencies where no version information was provided ie. empty fields.  I would like to automatically set the version fields for each dependency to latest. Essentially the pubspec equivalent to [this same problem in node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16074029/1464716).

Comment: Nor do I claim it to do that. Carefully read *all* answers to find that this is not something that exists in the pub tool. There may be packages that do that.

Comment: Please read *all* answers. Do not ignore answer just because they are not the accepted.

Comment: Your forward is great. The solutions there are not solutions. Hope this question forwards people via google.

Comment: What's unclear about my comment? You assume that this is possible with the pub tool. It's simply not. The second answer mentions that this is a feature that does not exist and provides methods of finding alternatives.

Comment: Since apparently you have a bone to pick.  The question is how to automate the process. I'm not going to fill in version information with web scraping tools or manual work.

Comment: Write your own script to do it. The second answer mentions 3rd party tools. You can adapt their code for the newer version of dart.

Comment: We agree. I just didn't want to hand hold the process is all and its a one time event given what I'm staring at.

Comment: I really don't know what kind of answer you expect to get beyond those shown in the linked question.

Comment: When a package is added to pubspec.yaml, the shorthand form plugin1: means that any version of the plugin1 package can be used. I think, in this case, you get the lastest version. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages