# How to update package.json to latest version of each package?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, npm-update

Before you flag it as duplicate, I have searched for the similar questions and none of them helped me.

Currently this is what I have tried:

1. Delete package-lock.json file.
2. Delete node_modules.
3. Run `npm update`
4. Run `npm install`

This would always allow me to install the latest (minor) version of the packages in node_modules, and update the package-lock.json file. However, the package.json file does not update.

For example, my moment is package.json is stated as "moment": "^2.27.0". After running above steps, package-lock.json will update to
"moment": {
"version": "2.29.1",
...}
But package.json will still be "moment": "^2.27.0".

What is the correct way to do this? Running `npm install moment` manually updates the package.json to become "moment": "^2.29.1" but its quite absurd if I have to run npm install for every single dependency?

**Edit**
Thanks to the selected answer, I realised that I do not actually need to update my package.json, as it shows compatible version, not exact version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-to-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version)

Comment: ^^^ basically, get **npm-check-updates** (ncu)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

Comment: does ncu update to the latest minor or major version? I don't want to upgrade to the next major version as it may break things

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`package.json` will not updated by `npm install`. That contains about dependencies and compatible version list.

`"moment": "^2.27.0"` meaning `allowed moment version: 2.27.0 <= version < 3.0.0`, not `allowed moment version = 2.27.0`. So when you run `npm install`, npm will install `the latest version of major version 2`(In your case, `2.29.1`), But `package.json` will not updated by that command. Because It not contains `installed version`, It contains `compatible version`.

However, `npm install moment` command do `install the latest version of moment`, So `package.json` updated the latest version, because `"^2.27.0"` is lower than `"^2.29.1"`.

Anyway, If you want to update your package.json, You can use `npm-check-updates` (a.k.a. `ncu`). [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16074029/7080061). If you not want running `ncu`, You can use `"latest"`(Example: `"moment": "latest"`) to install the latest version anytime.

Comment: does ncu update to the latest minor or major version? I don't want to upgrade to the next major version as it may break things

Comment: @Samson: Yes, `ncu` do. If you want use the latest version of major version 2, use `"moment": "<3"`.

Answer (score 20):

`npm outdated` lists all packages that can be updated with the current, wanted and latest version numbers.

- current  is the currently installed version
- wanted  is the last minor version update
- latest  is the latest major version update

To update all packages to latest just do:

```
npm outdated | awk 'NR>1 {print $1"@"$4}' | xargs npm install
```

which simply calls npm install with the latest version of each outdated package.

If you are using Windows Powershell, add `--%` after `awk` to prevent syntax errors:

```
npm outdated | awk --% 'NR>1 {print $1"@"$4}' | xargs npm install
```

It is highly recommended to check the resulting changes to your `packages.json` file just to make sure all changes are as expected.

Comment: Same here! I checked package.json and noticed it updated bootstrap from 4 to 5, which would have been undesirably, so just seconding @user1656671's recommendation to check the resulting changes.

Comment: And if you use [pnpm](https://pnpm.io), it's just `pnpm outdated`

Comment: woah, thanks for the one-liner, it did a nice job!

Comment: very nice, it works
according to me this is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

```
npx npm-check-updates -u
npm install
```