# npm update not updating all the outdated modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have certain node modules that i want to update. If i run `npm outdated` i see a list of modules and when i run `npm update` not all modules are updated.

I still see some in the list when i run `npm outdated`

my node version is `v12.16.2`

i see the below list when executing `npm outdated`

[image]

Below are the contents of my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "exporter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "api endpoint",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/node": "5.30",
    "abort-controller": "^3.0.0",
    "archiver": "^5.2.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.825.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bull": "^3.20.0",
    "bull-board": "^0.9.0",
    "config": "^3.3.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "csv": "^5.3.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "exceljs": "^4.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-basic-auth": "^1.2.0",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.2.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "generic-pool": "^3.7.1",
    "helmet": "^4.3.1",
    "jimp": "^0.16.1",
    "JSONStream": "^1.3.5",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.5.0",
    "pg": "^8.6.0",
    "pg-query-stream": "^4.1.0",
    "pm2": "^4.5.1",
    "puppeteer": "^5.5.0",
    "rate-limit-redis": "^2.0.0",
    "twitter": "^1.7.1",
    "underscore": "^1.12.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "/usr/local/bin/pm2 restart all --update-env"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

How can i update all the below modules, specifically `pm2` and `puppeteer`. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your package.json (particularly any dependencies/dev dependencies)? NPM will only update packages based on the semver version number specified (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-update - check caret and tilde dependencies). The reason for this is to help reduce the introduction of breaking changes to the codebase.

Comment: thanks @Bladeski, have updated the question with my `package.json`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-to-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version)

Answer (score 4):

[`npm update`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-update) respects semver constraints.

> This command will update all the packages listed to the latest version (specified by the tag config), respecting the semver constraints of both your package and its dependencies (if they also require the same package).

According to the `package.json`, the constraints are

- `@sentry/node`: exact version
- `bull-board`, `dotenv`, `pm2`, `puppeteer`: caret range

The packages are up-to-date according to these constraints.

To get the latest versions, you can install packages with the `@latest` tag.

Note that these are major version updates - things can break.