# Error with docker and react, digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, webpack

I have enrolled in a docker course and the instructor has provided a starter project with some rather old react code.

I dockerized the react project, here's the simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm i

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Then I built the image:

```
docker build -t goals-react .
```

And ran a container in attached mode:

```
docker run --name goals-app --rm -p 3000:3000 goals-react
```

This is the output I received:

```
> frontend@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.4/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /

Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)      
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
/app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)      
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
    at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
    at /app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.1.0
```

I assumed it was because the react project was using an old version of react, so I [upgraded the package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-to-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version) file with the following commands:

```
npx npm-check-updates -u
npm install
```

Then I removed and recreated the image, and then ran a new container:

```
docker rmi goals-react
docker build -t goals-react .
docker run --name goals-app --rm -p 3000:3000 goals-react
```

But to my surprise I received the same error. So I googled `digital envelope routines::unsupported` and I found yet another [stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported).

I executed the following command:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Then I rebuilt the image and restarted the container, but to no avail. I decided to read the error message more thoroughly and it seems to be a webpack error. I went to the webpack github page and I realised that someone else had the same issue, [right here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532), however the issue is closed. They also recommended the above command, but that obviously doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance for any feedback and help.

**Edit**:

As requested by @MikiBelavista, here is the package.json file:

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us your package.json.

Comment: Sure thing @MikiBelavista

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your line

```
"start": "react-scripts start",
```

to

```
"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
```

But be aware of that OpenSSL implementations of algorithms that have been deemed legacy. More [OpenSSl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man7/OSSL_PROVIDER-legacy.html)

Comment: This seems like a bad idea, right? Is there no solution that doesn't involve using insecure encryption?

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem and I used the n package and installed node 16.13.1 which solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Update the package.json "start" script to read:

```
"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
```

Make sure you rebuild the docker image, otherwise you will get the same error.

```
docker build --pull --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t yourappname:latest "."
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 an accepted solution is not working, because **node** image has moved to debian 12, where openssl 1.x.x is not installed, so it makes sense to switch to older base image

```
FROM node:18-bullseye
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a LTS version from node because  Node.js V17 and above  moved MD4 algorithms into OpenSSL 3.0’s legacy. You should specify a LTS version in the node option inside the Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM node:16.15.0
```

Currently 16.15.0 is the LTS, be sure to check the latest.
Also do not forget to create the image again.
adding --openssl-legacy-provide is insecure by the way.