# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree - for @mui/material

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

I am trying to install **Material UI** as described on the home page, but I get a dependency tree error:

```
C:\dev\shape-shop-front-end>npm install @mui/material
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree        
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.13.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.7.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!   @mui/material@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
```

In my **package.json** I have **"react": "^16.13.1"** .

As I understand it, this error is saying that a MUI package needs react 16.8.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, a sub-dependency of it, named @emotion/react@11.7.1, has listed the following peer dependencies you have to meet:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
  "react": ">=16.8.0"
}
```

source: https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/main/packages/react/package.json

I think this has to do with how new versions of NPM deal with peer dependencies: https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/

As your react version seems OK, I would go with this suggestion:

> You have the option to retry with --force to bypass the conflict or --legacy-peer-deps command to ignore peer dependencies entirely (this behavior is similar to versions 4-6).

Comment: does this mean I need to manually install `@babel/core` in my project?

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary, rather let NPM sort it out. Instead of simply running "npm install", try "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" or if that doesn't work out then "npm install --force". NPM installs peer deps like babel automatically by default, that extra flag helps resolve version conflicts if there are any.

Answer (score 7):

Try using --force.
That's what worked for me

```
npm install @mui/material --force
```

I have a feeling it's a dependency conflict that came with the recent React upgrade...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like updating dependencies in package.json is the only way to make this happen now.

```
$ npm install -g npm-check-updates
$ ncu -u
$ npm install
```

or see [how to update each dependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-to-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version)

after updating, now try to install your material UI.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
npm install @material-ui/core --force
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this it's work for me.

> npm install @material-ui/core --legacy-peer-deps

The use of the –legacy-peer-deps option is generally discouraged, as it can lead to potential compatibility issues and make it difficult to troubleshoot problems with your dependencies in the future.

Answer (score -1):

use this command instead

```
npm install @material-ui/core
```

If you're using it for the icon, then use this

```
npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons
```

Comment: Wrong answer as user is asking for `@mui` but the answer is given for `@material-ui`