# matrial ui not installing with npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui, package.json

///My console

```
PS F:> npm install  @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: picko-client@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.8.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.5.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       @mui/material@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@emotion/styled)
npm ERR!   1 more (@emotion/styled)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/material@5.5.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!   @mui/material@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\SAURABH\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SAURABH\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-31T06_00_07_287Z-debug.log
```

///my npm and node version

```
npm: '8.1.0',
node: '16.13.0',
```

///package.json file with all the dependecies

```
 {
      "name": "",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "react": "^18.0.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
     },
     "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
       "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
       ]
    },
   "browserslist": {
      "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
      ],
      "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
     ]
    }
  }
```

///I just created a react project and wanted to use material ui but not able to install with npm by the way this is the first time getting this error with material ui .it would be very helpful if somebody give me the right solution

Comment: Delete node_modules folder and try again.

Comment: its not working

Comment: Please attach package json.

Comment: yes i attached it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree - for @mui/material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70587214/eresolve-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-for-mui-material)

Comment: Change "react": "^18.0.0", "react-dom": "^18.0.0" to 17.0.0 and try again

Comment: i got the solution i had to change my react version to 17 from 18 but Do u think changing the version might degrade security?