# React Dependency Conflict Version 18.0 with Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, installation-package

I've tried all suggestion here but did not work.
[Issue with Material UI Icons npm installation : unable to resolve dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718054/issue-with-material-ui-icons-npm-installation-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tre)  nor this one below:
[create-react-app dependency version issues with React 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71835697/create-react-app-dependency-version-issues-with-react-18)
What can be done to solve this issue, please? below is my package.lock.json.

```js
     "name": "cashflowbr",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "cashflowbr",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
        "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.5",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.2",
        "@mui/material": "^5.6.2",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
      }
```

Comment: Can you please attach the error(s) that you get?

Comment: Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/components/NavBar.js 5:0-50

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/AppBar' in '/home/flavio/CashFlowBr/cashflowbr/src/components'


ERROR in ./src/components/NavBar.js 6:0-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/ToolBar' in '/home/flavio/CashFlowBr/cashflowbr/src/components'


ERROR in ./src/components/NavBar.js 7:0-53

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Typography' in '/home/flavio/CashFlowBr/cashflowbr/src/components'

Comment: My NavBar.js file:                                             
 import React from 'react';
import {AppBar} from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import ToolBar from '@material-ui/core/ToolBar';
import Typografy from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const NavBar = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <ToolBar>
                    <Typografy variant="title" color="inherit">
                        CashFlowBR - Sistema de Gerenciamento Financeiro
                    </Typografy>
                </ToolBar>
            </AppBar>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appears that you are attempting to import MUI version 4 components while installing MUI version 5.

Your imports should be from `@mui/material` (version 5) and not from `@material-ui/core` (version 4).

### Option 1

Change your imports to use the installed library (`@mui/material`), ex:

```
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
```

### Option 2

Change your `package.json` to install MUIv4.

Remove:

```
"@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
...
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.2",
"@mui/material": "^5.6.2",
```

... and add:

```
"@material-ui/core": "4.11.3",
"@material-ui/icons": "4.11.3",
```

Finally, run `npm install`.  Delete your `node_modules` folder and then `npm install` if you have any issues after that.

Comment: I would like to add this: npm install @mui/icons-material instead of npm install @material-ui/icons