# Violation Avoid using document.write(). Brovser-sync issue

Tags: html, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

Had a message in console that says to avoid using document.write(). [how it looks in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HETls.png)

Its took a while to find how to fix it or even find where problem is,
couse have this part of code:

```
 <script id="__bs_script__">
            //<![CDATA[
            document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.27.11'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
            //]]>
        </script>
```

Which appears from some library i guess (I'm didn't wrote it).

After 30min looking for that problem found that it fixes with updating `browser-sync in package.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it by updating browser-sync, also find that useful post to update all dependencies

[How to update each dependency in package.json to the latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-to-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version)