# How do I update development dependencies with NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

Here's the part of my `package.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "~3.8",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

I'm running the following commands:

```
gulp --version

CLI version 3.8.7
Local version 3.8.6

npm update
gulp --version

CLI version 3.8.7
Local version 3.8.6

rm -Rf ./node_modules/
npm install

gulp --version

CLI version 3.8.7
Local version 3.8.7
```

The `npm update` command has no effect.

It's only after I manually delete the `node_modules` directory and run `npm install` development packages are updated. What is the reason for this? Is it possible to actually update development packages without such a hassle?

Comment: Did you try `npm update -g`? I suppose gulp is installed globally.
 
`npm update` should update devDependencies

Comment: Gulp is installed both globally and locally. That's why it shows two versions (CLI and Local). I'm trying to update local development version, but it's not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update devDependencies in NPM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068592/how-do-i-update-devdependencies-in-npm)

Answer (score 7):

Just run the following command to update the devDependencies.

```
npm update
```

Edited, If above command does not work then  try to use following.

```
npm update -D
```

OR

```
npm update --save-dev
```

Comment: @HassanSiddique that's the command that doesn't work. Solved my problem with npm-check-updates package though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the previous answer receives upvotes if the OP mentioned that `npm update` did not work for him.

I have recently stumbled upon the same problem, in particular running `npm update -g` did not have any effect on my `devDependecies` in `package.json` file.

I gave a go to [npm-check-updates package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) by running `npm install npm-check-updates -g`.
To see outdated dependencies run `ncu`. Then run `ncu -u` to update all the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

to update gulp server you can use

```
npm i -g npm
```

Which update lates version of it

Answer (score -2):

The command below will update only the devDependecies

```
npm update --save-dev
```