# Grunt - how update specific dependency?

Tags: gruntjs

Is this possible? For example I would like to update grunt-jscs-checker from version 0.4.1 to latest.

Answer to update all: [How do I update devDependencies in NPM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068592/how-do-i-update-devdependencies-in-npm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to update  only, just run `npm update <package name>` - so `npm update grunt-jscs-checker` in your case.

Comment: you're welcome. Could you mark the question as answered then?