# How to update devDependencies only?

Tags: npm

How to update devDependencies and devDependencies only through npm?

The accepted answer in the similar question is not an answer to the question: [How do I update devDependencies in NPM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068592/how-do-i-update-devdependencies-in-npm) but how to update all dependencies instead.

Answer (score -1):

To update package.json use:

```
npm update -D
```

Comment: @JAN What information do you have in console. Should be some error. In my case all is working