# What does npm install --legacy-peer-deps do exactly? When is it recommended / What's a potential use case?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

Just ran into this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: nexttwin@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from react-hook-mousetrap@2.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-hook-mousetrap
npm ERR!   react-hook-mousetrap@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
```

The module I am trying to install seems to have a different peer dependency from what I have installed. It seems like npm changed its behaviour in this regard and now lets the install fail.

What can I do now to fix this? I don't want to downgrade my React version for this.

I know there is a flag called `--legacy-peer-deps` but I am not sure what exactly this does and whether it's recommended to use it / what the potential disadvantages are? I assume there is a reason npm did let the install fail.

It's just strange because I was using `yarn` up until very recently and everything was fine.

Comment: I just did `npm install xxxx --legacy-peer-deps`. The install worked, but I'm not sure whether it was a good idea to solve it this way, because I don't quite understand the flag, that's why I'm asking. But haven't yet found out what the flag *really* does! :(

Comment: Specifically I wonder how `--legacy-peer-deps` is different than `--force`, because my `npm` recommends using either approach:  `npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: @TheRedPea ever find the answer? My npm also states both are the same but now I read this I am concerned they are not

Comment: No @Sammaye I don't think I found the answer

Comment: @antonwilhelm could you find an answer to this cause currently I have the same error.

Comment: I had the same issue. 17.0.1 is a higher version comparing to 16.8.0. How come NPM consider this is a conflict? This does not make sense.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Here's how I solved this problem:

**First, what's happening:** react-hook-mousetrap is looking for react@16.8.0, but it is not finding it. Instead it is finding @react17.0.1, which is a newer version. For some reason mousetrap doesn't like this newer version, and you are being notified (it is not a big deal, but they decided it was worth stopping your build).

**One solution:** forcibly install the specific version of **react** that mousetrap wants:

```
yarn add react@16.8.0
```

What this does is roll back your react version to a slightly older one that is compatible with mousetrap. You won't notice any difference, and in future iterations, hopefully mousetrap is updated, so this goes away.

**Another solution:** make a sweeping decision to not install any older version dependencies:

```
npm add xxxx --legacy-peer-deps
```

What this does is ignore old dependencies for this package. It is more comprehensive, and makes a lot of the decisions for you.

Comment: --legacy-peer-deps does not roll back any dependencies to any version. It simply just doesn't try to install peer dependencies automatically.

Comment: @dtabuenc - I've updated. Please edit, if you think this is still incorrect / misleading. Thx

Comment: What I don't understand is that https://npm.anvaka.com/#/view/2d/react-hook-mousetrap does not show such a dependency in the first place?!

Comment: is there any way that we can just change version of any package and do it with npm install only?

Comment: @redevill Peer dependencies are unfortunately not shown on npmjs.com, you need to look at the [`package.json` file of the library](https://github.com/olup/react-hook-mousetrap/blob/master/package.json#L30-L33) itself.

Comment: what should i use instead of xxxx should it be react or the plugin

Answer (score 644):

## TL;DR:

- NPM v7+ installs peerDependencies [by default](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/implemented/0025-install-peer-deps.md); this is **not** the case with previous versions of NPM.
- NPM modules must name **specific versions** of their peerDependencies
- If you already have a peerDependency installed, but not with a version named by the module, then NPM v7+ will throw an error
- Adding `--legacy-peer-deps` ignores this new requirement, at the risk of introducing breaking changes

### --legacy-peer-deps restores peerDependency installation behavior from NPM v4 thru v6

One way of thinking of this flag is that it isn't doing something new; rather it's telling NPM *not* to do something new, since NPM v7 **now installs peerDependencies by default**.

In many cases, this is leading to version conflicts, which will break the installation process.

The `--legacy-peer-deps` flag was introduced with v7 as a way to bypass peerDependency auto-installation; it tells NPM to ignore peer deps and proceed with the installation anyway. **This is how things used to be with NPM v4 thru v6.**

If you're unclear about the difference between regular deps and peer deps, here is a bit of context:

#### Dependencies vs peerDependencies

**Dependencies:** Libraries or modules that an NPM module needs *in order to work in production*. (Example: I recently built a pie chart mocking library that uses [Chance.js](https://chancejs.com/) to calculate random numbers within a specified range; Chance is therefore a *dependency* of my module.)

**peerDependencies**: A peer dependency is a *specific version or set of versions* of a third-party software library that *a module is designed to work with*. They're similar in concept to the relationship between a browser extension and a browser. (Example: [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) has two quite logical peerDependencies: `react` and `redux`.)

### This issue is being driven, in part, by React v17+

Due to the large number of modules that haven't specifically added React v17 (or more recently, React 18) as a peerDependency, it's now commonplace to encounter the `unable to resolve dependency tree` error when running npm installs within a v17 React application.

This error will fire whenever a module (or any of its own dependencies) lists a previous major version of React as a peerDependency without *specifically including* React v17 as well.

(*Note:* Similar behavior will occur with the major-version update of any other framework or library.)

### How to check peerDependencies for any given module

NPM itself doesn't list peer deps on the pages of a given module. However, there is a simple workaround to check for peer deps, either before or after install. Simply run:

`npm info name-of-module peerDependencies`

This command will return the name of each peerDependency along with all compatible version(s).

Comment: Very nice explanation! But am still confused by: "Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@11.2.13" which is in my root. It apparently conflicts with "@angular/fire@6.1.4" which states a need for a compatible version of: "peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0" - Why the error? These don't appear to be in conflict?

Comment: @redevill Can you send a CodeSandbox that reproduces the issue? I'm happy to take a look

Comment: In another thread - I had someone else pointed out that npm 7.11.? needed to be updated, and that was the probable cause. I have not proved this, due to time constraints I pulled the --legacy flag. Will try and return when I have a moment. Thank you!

Comment: does this works for yarn ? I didn't see this flag in yarn's help

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira no, because Yarn 1.x treats peer dependencies the same way as npm 4-6, so no flag is needed

Comment: Why can't there be two versions and each dep using the peerdep version that they need? Or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Quick Question: So, as I dev with React 17, it makes sense to use --legacy-peer-deps flag despite the risk?

Comment: npm info name-of-module peerDependencies is not found in my npm, the global one is one of the latest

Comment: @CarmineTambascia are you replacing `name-of-module` with the actual module name? Try running `npm info react-redux peerDependencies` to see if that gets you a result.

Comment: @VuTrongNghia I wouldn't recommend that approach in a production environment.

Comment: @ChrisPerry definitely

Comment: Say I am developing module X.   I’m not using React at all.   But I choose to use dependency Y which _can work with_ React (ie has peerDependency React).   Do I now have to list React in X’s peerDependency lust too else my install will fail?

Comment: Can we consider that if it occurs for devDependencies, using --legacy-peer-deps is not a big deal ? To prevent crashes,... in production.

Comment: Shouldn't this rename to `--dont-install-peer-deps` or something similar then?

Comment: @Adev I see what you're saying. Naming in software is a challenging (and highly opionated) endeavor. I would personally favor your approach (probably with a more concise `--ignore-peer-deps`) -- either way you word it, the intent is more immediately obvious than "legacy". Selfishly, I probably wouldn't have as many votes if this were the case, but that's the only drawback I can think of :3

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but using the `--ignore-peer-deps` is only a half-side solution when manually installing packages.  It fails to apply to any future rebuilds of the project when using `npm i` in new environments such as when building a new environment with continual integration, or when a new team member tries to build the project from scratch.

Answer (score 13):

[`legacy-peer-deps`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps):

> - Default: false
> - Type: Boolean
>
> Causes npm to completely ignore `peerDependencies` when building a package tree, as in npm versions 3 through 6.
>
> If a package cannot be installed because of overly strict `peerDependencies` that collide, it provides a way to move forward resolving the situation.
>
> This differs from `--omit=peer`, in that `--omit=peer` will avoid unpacking `peerDependencies` on disk, but will still design a tree such that `peerDependencies` could be unpacked in a correct place.
>
> Use of `legacy-peer-deps` is not recommended, as it will not enforce the `peerDependencies` contract that meta-dependencies may rely on.

---

If you want to continue using `legacy-peer-deps` without needing to add the flag to every command, you can configure it in your `.npmrc` (either at the project level or globally on your machine):

```
echo "legacy-peer-deps=true" >> .npmrc
```

[npmrc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/npmrc):

> npm gets its config settings from the command line, environment variables, and `npmrc` files.
>
> The `npm config` command can be used to update and edit the contents of the user and global npmrc files.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved (with yarn) adding the following to package.json

```
"resolutions": {
    "**/react": "17.0.2",
    "**/react-dom": "17.0.2"
},
```

Comment: is there a way that we can use with npm install only and change any package version in package.json?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to block installing older dependencies, you can make npm neglect those warnings by forcing the script you're running. `--force`

Answer (score 3):

`--legacy-peer-deps` jumps the installation of all the peer dependencies and gives warnings about the peer deps to notice developers install them manually. When encountering the peer deps conflicts, other than `--legacy-peer-deps`, another choice is use `--force`. 
The official doc of handling peer deps conflicts is [this](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/implemented/0031-handling-peer-conflicts.md)

p.s.
Correct the top answer: `--legacy-peer-deps` restores peerDependency installation behavior from NPM **v3** thru v6, rather than v4 thru v6.

Answer (score 1):

I had a dependency error after running the command `npm audit fix --force`.

I used this command to fix the error `npm add xxxx --legacy-peer-deps`.

Answer (score 0):

One other way is to downgrade your npm version to version 6

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 1. This has no supporting comment as to 'why' version 6 is any better, or what downgrading would do.
2. This is recommending going backwards in versions, which is not often advisable and has it's own issues.

Answer (score 0):

The `--legacy-peer-deps` flag in `npm install` allows installing packages even if their peer dependencies do not strictly match the versions specified in the project's `package.json`.

It is used in cases of compatibility issues, particularly when dealing with older projects or packages that have not been updated to support the latest `npm` version.

It's a temporary solution. So recommend updating the dependencies for a better and long-term solution.