# Cant resolve dependency on Boilerplate project

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I've downloaded a [Angular 5 / .NET 5 project](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates), and normally when I run the command npm install, I don't have any problems.

But since yesterday when downloading a project and running this command I get this error:

```
C:\Users\ca\source\repos\CCM\angular\src>npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: CCM@4.7.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@10.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"^10.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@">=2.3.1 <10.0.0 || >9.0.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.1.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.2.0-beta <10.0.0" from codelyzer@5.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/codelyzer
npm ERR!   dev codelyzer@"^5.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\ca\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ca\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-24T08_34_44_177Z-debug.log
```

Normally I don't have any problem with this command so I'm wondering if it's a problem with my setup or with the project.

I can submit the full report if requested.

Comment: I know you're an elder here, but could it be an NPM, Node or angular cli version issue ?

Comment: @ModarNa Honestly I have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: what's your npm and node version.

Comment: @ModarNa Npm version is 7.7.0 and Node version is 12.14.1

Comment: some indicated it is an NPM issue, others claimed that it is an dependency issue in codelyzer [check this](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/issues/967).
you can try `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: @ModarNa That did the trick, thank you so much. consider leaving an answer with your findings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

considering the line

```
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@">=2.3.1 <10.0.0 || >9.0.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.1.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.2.0-beta <10.0.0" from codelyzer@5.2.2
```

the error is from the codelyzer@5.2.2 dependencies, I found [this closed issue](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/issues/967) on github which indicates that  it is not really a problem 
running `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` could solve it, for more information [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh).

Answer (score 0):

Found out that codelyzer is actually not needed for Angular 13 and newer, see [Codelyzer requires Angular 9 instead of Angular 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69809094/codelyzer-requires-angular-9-instead-of-angular-10).

**Original answer before finding out:**

As suggested in codelyzer GitHub issue mentioned in the other answer, upgrading codelyzer helped me:

1. Upgrade codelyzer to version to "^6.0.0"
2. Remove "package-lock.json"
3. Remove node_modules folder
4. npm install works now

I know it's an old question, but it happened to me having Angular 13 project working normally and then break. Not really sure why now, though.