# Codelyzer requires Angular 9 instead of Angular 10

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, yarnpkg, codelyzer

When I am running the command `npm ls -json` in my node js project I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! missing: @angular/core@9.0.0, required by codelyzer@6.0.2
npm ERR! missing: @angular/compiler@9.0.0, required by codelyzer@6.0.2
```

`@angular/core` and `@angular/compiler` are already installed in the dependencies of my project, but with version 10.2.4

The error only occures when I am running `yarn install` to install my packages. If I am using `npm install` everything works fine, but takes a while.

Is there any version of codelyzer that uses Angular 10 instead of Angular 9 or some other package that solves the same problem?

Environment:

- OS: Windows
- Package Manager: yarn
- Angular version: 10

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out, that Codelyzer is deprecated and I had to remove it and install "eslint" package instead. EsLint has included all features of codelyzer.

Answer (score 3):

I found this [Github](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/issues/967) conversastion and based on that
I just had to update the version for Angular 10. The Codelayzer version was @6.0.0