# Error: No version of chokidar is available. Tried chokidar@2 and chokidar@3. after upgrading npm to 7.*.*

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, create-react-app

using ejected CRA , it compiles successfully and then it breaks showing below error.. it started happend when i updated npm to 7 from 6

```
You can now view webrms in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3001
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.160:3001

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

/home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/watchpack/lib/chokidar.js:17
throw new Error(
^

Error: No version of chokidar is available. Tried chokidar@2 and chokidar@3.
You could try to manually install any chokidar version.
chokidar@3: Error: Cannot find module 'chokidar'
Require stack:
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/watchpack/lib/chokidar.js
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/watchpack/lib/watcherManager.js
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/watchpack/lib/watchpack.js
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/webpack/lib/node/NodeWatchFileSystem.js
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/webpack/lib/node/NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/scripts/start.js
chokidar@2: Error: Cannot find module 'watchpack-chokidar2'
Require stack:
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/watchpack/lib/chokidar.js
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/watchpack/lib/watcherManager.js
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/watchpack/lib/watchpack.js
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/webpack/lib/node/NodeWatchFileSystem.js
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/webpack/lib/node/NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
- /home/murtaza/umai/webrms/scripts/start.js

    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/watchpack/lib/chokidar.js:17:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/murtaza/umai/webrms/node_modules/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js:9:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
```

does anyone have facing same issue if yes then whats the solution ?

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error when using `npm@7.13.0` and was able to fix it by either downgrading to `npm@7.5.4` or by running `npm update --force` command.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

For more information have a look on:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10811

Comment: Thats hilarious.

Answer (score 1):

its something definitely wrong with npm `7.*.*` .. i tried `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` and it worked for me...

however it shouldn't be like this and dependencies should handled in latest stable version..

here is the detailed reasoning of why it may cause:

[What does npm install --legacy-peer-deps do exactly? When is it recommended / What's a potential use case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh/66620869#66620869)